# Is it possible for properties on one constructor function to be inherited by another constructor function?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

With javascript, you can have one object inherit properties from another, so that if a property is not found on the first object, the second object is searched for it. By reassigning the `prototype` property on a constructor function, you can create chains of many objects to search for a property.

For example:

```
var X = function() {};
X.prototype.x = "x";

var Y = function() {};
Y.prototype = new X();
Y.prototype.y = "y";

var z = new Y();
z.z = "z";

///////////////

console.log(z.z); // searches z for property 'z', finds it and returns 'z'

console.log(z.y); // searches z, fails, searches z.[[hidden_prototype]] 
                  // (which is Y.prototype), finds it and returns 'y'

console.log(z.x); // searches z, fails, searches Y.prototype, fails, 
                  // searches Y.prototype.[[hidden_prototype]]
                  // (which is X.prototype), finds it and returns "x"
```

I was wondering though whether it was possible to extend that to properties on the constructor functions, ie `X` and `Y` in the above code. For example, is there a way to alter the above code so that the following will also work:

```
X.val = 42;

console.log(Y.val); // returns 42
```

This would work if `Y.[[hidden_prototype]] === X`, but I have no idea how to set that when `X` and `Y` also have to be constructor functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the first related [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340383/can-a-javascript-object-have-a-prototype-chain-but-also-be-a-function)

You can do something like :

```
function Y(){}
function X(){}
Y.__proto__=X;
X.val=42;
console.log(Y.val);//42
```

Though it is apparently not standard

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted to know, didn't see the related link when I typed the question. By the looks of it the possible answers lists is updated by the contents of not just the title, but also the text - should check it again after typing the question :)

Comment: You should not use the non-standard, deprecated __proto__ property. It is not widely supported and will be removed from the browsers that do support it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a clone function first developed by Lasse Reichstein Nielson and popularised by Douglas Crockford as "beget":

```
var clone = (function() {
  var f = function(){};
  return function(obj) {
    f.prototype = obj;
    return new f();
  }
}());
```

To set X as Y[[Prototype]]:

```
function X(){}
var Y = clone(X);
```

However Y will be an object, not a function. Functions can only be created by the Function constructor. How it creates new functions is defined in ECMA-262, you can't influence which object it uses as the [[Prototype]] object because functions must inherit from Function.prototype and Object.prototype, so it can't allow just any object to be inserted as the [[Prototype]].