# Achieving prototype inheritance with private variable in parent object

Tags: javascript, prototype

I tried to achieve the prototypical inheritance, in when there is private variables in parent object.

Consider a code like,

```
function Piece(isLiveArg) { 
    var isLive = isLiveArg; // I dont wish to make this field as public. I want it to be private.
    this.isLive = function(){ return isLive;}
}    

Piece.prototype.isLive = function () { return this.isLive(); }       

function Pawn(isLiveArg) { 
    // Overriding takes place by below assignment, and getPoints got vanished after this assignment.
    Pawn.prototype = new Piece(isLiveArg);           
}

Pawn.prototype.getPoints = function(){
    return 1;
}

var p = new Pawn(true);

console.log("Pawn live status : " + p.isLive());
```

But, no private variable `isLive`  exists on parent object, and only public variables exists, then inheritance can able to achieve this very easily.,
Like in this link., http://jsfiddle.net/tCTGD/3/.

**So, How would I achieve the same prototypical inheritance, in when there is private variables in parent object.**

Answer (score 5):

The way you are setting up inheritance is wrong. The assignment to `Func.prototype` should be *outside* the constructor. Then, if you apply the parent constructor function to the new "child" object, it will assign the closure to it as well.

Example:

```
function Piece(isLiveArg) { 
    var isLive = isLiveArg;
    this.isLive = function(){ return isLive;}
}

function Pawn(isLiveArg) { 
     // apply parent constructor
     Piece.call(this, isLiveArg);   
}

// set up inheritance
Pawn.prototype = Object.create(Piece.prototype);
Pawn.prototype.constructor = Pawn;

Pawn.prototype.getPoints = function(){
    return 1;
}
```

Have a look at [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196) to get an idea why `Object.create` is better to set up inheritance.

There is no sense in trying to create prototype functions that access "private properties". Only closures defined in the constructor can access those variables.