# Prototypal Inheritence in Javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

How to pass values to super class constructors in Javascript.

In the following code snippet

```
(function wrapper() {
var id = 0;

window.TestClass = TestClass;

function TestClass() {
    id++;
    this.name = 'name_' + id;
    function privateFunc() {
        console.log(name);
    }
    function publicFunc() {
        privateFunc();
    }

    this.publicFunc = publicFunc;
}

function TestString() {
    this.getName = function() {
        console.log("***" + this.name + "****************");
    }
}

TestClass.prototype = new TestString(); 
})();
```

How do I pass values to the TestString constructor? Currently, the super class method is using value using 'this' keyword. Is there a way to directly pass values to the super class constructor. Also, I want to see a simple example of extending String. That would demystify a lot of things.

Comment: I recommend to not use `TestClass.prototype = new TestString();` to establish inheritance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196

Comment: It looks like you will be using "private variables", then prototypal inheritance doesn't work (nor does anything else that works on object properties)

Comment: @Esailija..can you please elaborate. A little example with help here. Thanks.

Comment: @Gopal here are multiple examples that show difference between variables and properties http://jsfiddle.net/VjZnn/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 Maybe this is helpful how to use function constructors, prototype, inheritance and overriding functions. It doesn't have the module pattern used for privates sometimes because that'll screw up your prototype (as mentioned before). It shows how not to use new TestString to inherit and explains why you don't define functions in the constructor body (have them on the prototype)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code in the constructor of `TestClass()`.

```
TestString.apply(this, arguments);
```

This will call the constructor with the new object as its context.

However, note that establishing the `[[Prototype]]` chain with `TestClass.prototype = new TestString();` will have already called the constructor once.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HytgX/).

> I want to see a simple example of extending `String`.

You can augment its `prototype` property.

```
String.prototype.endsWidth = function(str) {
    return this.slice(-str.length) === str;
};
```

Comment: @alex..thanks for quick response. Can you please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gCwZD/1/ I have commented out the prototype part, still, it works!! How is that possible?

Comment: @Gopal: Because you didn't add anything to `TestString.prototype`, so it does not matter whether you set it or not. I recommend to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript to get a better idea about what the `prototype` property actually is.

Comment: @FelixKling..I looked at your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392857/benefits-of-using-object-create-for-inheritance Thanks for great explanation. But, I'm not getting one thing here. Why is it mandatory that I call super class constructor. For instance can you please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AvVG2/1/ ?