# what is javascript prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am a bit curious about javascript prototype
I found sample in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)
and I made little modification so I can try it like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        function Product(name, price) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
        }

        function Food(name, price) {
            Product.call(this, name, price);
            this.category = 'food';
            this.otherName = name;
        }
        Food.prototype = new Product();

        function Toy(name, price) {
            Product.call(this, name, price);
            this.category = 'toy';
        }
        Toy.prototype = new Product();

        var cheese = new Food('feta', 5);
        var fun = new Toy('robot', 40);
        var prod = new Product('test', 20);
        console.log(cheese);
        console.log(fun);
        console.log(prod);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and it returns like this

```
cheese = Food {name: "feta", price: 5, category: "food", otherName: "feta", name: undefined, price: undefined}
fun = Toy {name: "robot", price: 40, category: "toy", name: undefined, price: undefined}
prod = Product {name: "test", price: 20}
```

its make property `name` and `price` twice, is it more efficient if we distinguish `Food.prototype = new Product();` and `Toy.prototype = new Product();`

Why must I use that line?

Comment: I don't understand the question. But instead of using `.protoype = new Foo()` you should use `Object.create` to set up inheritance. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196.

Comment: I think that's a mistake in the article. Doing `Food.prototype = new Product();` seems to be pointless.

Comment: @freakish: I think it's to demonstrate inheritance.

Comment: @simonzack In that article `Product.call` is used to demonstrate constructor chaining. `Food.prototype = new Product();` is confusing in that context imho.

Answer (score 3):

Every JavaScript object has a second JavaScript object (or null,
but this is rare) associated with it. This second object is known as a prototype, and the
first object inherits properties from the prototype.

All objects created by object literals have the same prototype object, and we can refer
to this prototype object in JavaScript code as `Object.prototype`. Objects created using
the new keyword and a constructor invocation use the value of the prototype property
of the constructor function as their prototype. So the object created by `new Object()`
inherits from `Object.prototype` just as the object created by `{}` does. Similarly, the
object created by `new Array()` uses `Array.prototype` as its prototype, and the object
created by `new Date()` uses `Date.prototype` as its prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Well, The prototype property allows you to add properties and methods to an object.

Sample to understand:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

function employee(name,jobtitle,born)
{
this.name=name;
this.jobtitle=jobtitle;
this.born=born;
}
var fred=new employee("Fred Flintstone","Caveman",1970);

employee.prototype.salary=null;

fred.salary=20000;

document.write(fred.salary);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In above sample we are adding one more property (salary) to the employee using *prototype*.

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

like OOP, all objects in JS are descendent of Object class, they inherit all properties from Object.prototype, while you can override them.
Object can have null prototype too, i.e. Object.create(null)..