# Function that extend another function with prototype

Tags: javascript, function, class, object, prototype

This is my JavaScript code:

```
function animal(){
    var animal_sound;
    this.animal = function(sound){
        animal_sound = sound;
    }

    this.returnSound = function(){
        return animal_sound;
    }
}

function cat(){
    this.cat = function(sound){
        this.animal(sound);
    }
}
cat.prototype = new animal()
cat.prototype.constructor = cat;

//Create the first cat
var cat1 = new cat();
cat1.cat('MIAO');//the sound of the first cat

//Create the second cat
var cat2 = new cat();
cat2.cat('MIAAAAUUUUUU');//the sound of the second cat

alert(cat1.returnSound()+' '+cat2.returnSound());
```

Simply I have the `cat` function that extend the `animal` function. Than I have created two different cats (`cat1` and `cat2`). Each cat has the own sound but when I print their sounds I obtain:

> `MIAAAAUUUUUU MIAAAAUUUUUU`

The `cat2` sound overwrite the `cat1` sound and I would not want this.

I would like to obtain:

> `MIAO MIAAAAUUUUUU`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `animal()` and `.returnSound()` methods are on the prototype, and so they're shared between all instances of `cat`.

Because they were created in the `animal` constructor, and uses a variable in that constructor's scope, every time you call `.animal()`, you're overwriting the same variable that is used by `.animal()` and `.returnSound()`.

To do what you want, you'll need to create a new `.animal()` and `.returnSound()` method for each `cat`.

---

```
function animal(){
    var animal_sound;
    this.animal = function(sound){
        animal_sound = sound;
    }

    this.returnSound = function(){
        return animal_sound;
    }
}

function cat(){
    animal.call(this); // apply the `animal()` function to the new `cat` object
    this.cat = function(sound){
        this.animal(sound);
    }
}
cat.prototype = new animal()
cat.prototype.constructor = cat;
```

Now when you create the cats, they'll have their own `.animal()` and `.returnSound()` methods, which will be created in a separate invocation of `animal` for each `cat`, so there will be a new `animal_sound` for each of those pairs of methods.

```
var cat1 = new cat();
cat1.cat('MIAO');

var cat2 = new cat();
cat2.cat('MIAAAAUUUUUU');

alert(cat1.returnSound()+' '+cat2.returnSound()); // MIAO MIAAAAUUUUUU
```

---

Of course, in doing this, you're not taking much advantage of prototypal inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are setting the prototype up with

```
cat.prototype = new animal()
```

Each animal instance has its own "private" `animal_sound` variable, but all `cat` instances inherit from **the same** `animal` instance and thus they "share" this variable.

Instead you should invoke the `animal` for *each* `cat` instance:

```
function cat(){
    animal.call(this);

    this.cat = function(sound){
        this.animal(sound);
    }
}
```

You don't even need to assign anything to `cat.prototype` in this case. However, if you plan to add methods to the prototype (which you should), use `Object.create` to set up inheritance. More info here: [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196).