# Does calling Class.prototype = new MyClass() ensure superclass is reinstantiated each time?

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects

I am using:

```
var ReportsServiceCall = function () { };

ReportsServiceCall.prototype = new ServiceCall();
```

With this code, is the `ServiceCall` a fresh instance each time a `new ReportsServiceCall` is created? I need it to be so.

Comment: I think he's asking whether it's a new instance of ServiceCall on each new ReportsServiceCall.

Comment: Yes, I'm after what regulus described.

Comment: Your parent's instance variables are now put on the prototype of the Child and it's not a good way to have to create an instance of Parent to set 50% of the inheritance of Child. More on prototype here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nope**

As you have it written, the prototype is only setup once. However, that's not a very good way to write it.

I would write it like this

```
var ReportsServiceCall = function () {

  // parent constructor; optional
  ServiceCall.call(this);
};

// setup prototype; see comment below
ReportsServiceCall.prototype = Object.create(ServiceCall.prototype, {
  constructor: {
    value: ReportsServiceCall,
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
  }
});
```

**Note:** Aside from setting `super_`, this is how node.js is doing vanilla inheritance in their [util.inherits](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L571-L581) function.

This is very effective technique once you understand how it works.

Comment: I agree with using Object.create for prototype part and +1 for re using ServiceCall constructor. The second parameter of Object.create cannot be used in older browsers even if you shim it. For the older browsers it's saver to do: `ReportsServiceCall.prototype = Object.create(ServiceCall.prototype);ReportsServiceCall.prototype.constructor = ReportsServiceCall;`

Comment: Thanks guys, looks like I'm going to drop support for ie8 then and go with this. (oh how I've waited for this day)

Answer (score 2):

> With this code, is the ServiceCall a fresh instance each time?

No and it's not a good way to setup inheritance. At the moment you are calling `new ServiceCall`, you actually don't want to create an instance of `ServiceCall` (which arguments would you pass if the constructor requires parameters?). All you really want is add `ServiceCall`'s prototype to `ReportsServiceCall`'s prototype chain.

You should use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) instead and call the superclass constructor inside the child class constructor:

```
var ReportsServiceCall = function () {
    ServiceCall.call(this);
};

ReportsServiceCall.prototype = Object.create(ServiceCall.prototype);
```

See [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196) for an extended explanation of this pattern.

Comment: +1 As javascript accepts variadic arguments, maybe to use `apply` .. ?

Comment: @KenKin, it's unlikely the parent constructor would take the exact same arguments sent to the child.

Comment: @FelixKling, you might want to consider passing `{constructor: {value: ReportsServiceCall}}` to `Object.create`. Otherwise you end up with `(new ReportServiceCall).constructor.name; // ""`

Comment: @maček: Hmm .. the inconsistency of the parameters order might be a controversial design problem ..

Comment: @KenKin, in some cases you might have the same parameters; It's not a "design problem" to make the child constructor accept different arguments...

Comment: @maček: Okay, so let me reword *problem* to *decision*.

Comment: @maček Because JavaScript doesn't have named arguments as (for example) python I usually pass a args object. This object can be passed along through the function chain that make up a certain process and each function reads and sets whatever it needs. You can't do `someFunction(spacing=15, step=2);` but you can do `someFunction({spacing:15,step:2});`. This is particularly handy when you use mediator pattern and not sure in a certain function what the next function will be.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO not, as you are setting the prototype just once

Comment: Well, as long as it was an honest opinion :)

Answer (score 1):

The prototype is only a single object that will be shared by all of the instances of `ReportsServiceCall`. If you need the `ServiceCall` constructor to be called for each `ReportsServiceCall` instance, you can do this:

```
function ReportsServiceCall() {
  ServiceCall.call(this);
};
ReportsServiceCall.prototype = new ServiceCall();
ReportsServiceCall.prototype.constructor = ReportsServiceCall;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Not really.**

A `ReportsServiceCall` *is a* `ServiceCall`, but create a `ReportsServiceCall` with `new` doesn't make it have its own properties which assigned in the constructor of `ServiceCall`.

Look at the following example:

```
var ServiceCall=function () {
    this.Id=Math.random();
};

var ReportsServiceCall=function () {
};

ReportsServiceCall.prototype=new ServiceCall();

var x=new ReportsServiceCall();
var y=new ReportsServiceCall();

alert(x.Id===y.Id); // true .. so, what Id for?
```

One of the solutions is:

```
var ReportsServiceCall=function () {
    ServiceCall.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: `ServiceCall.apply(this, arguments)` is not ideal. It's unlikely the parent constructor would take the same arguments sent to the child. Probably better to provide the minimum solution.