# What is the difference between A.prototype = B.prototype and A.prototype = new B()?

Tags: javascript, prototype, new-operator

I am learning JavaScript and found two ways of assigning prototype.

The first is `A.prototype = B.prototype` and the second is `A.prototype = new B()`

For example:

```
function A() {
  console.log("A!")
}

function B() {
  console.log("B!")
}

// First case
A.prototype = B.prototype;
a = new A();  // a instanceof A,B

// Second case
A.prototype = new B();
a = new A();  // a instanceof A,B
```

1. Is there any difference and which way to prefer?
2. Is there any other way to assign prototype?

Update:

As Felix Kling advised there is a third way to assign a prototype:

```
A.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype);
```

Comment: *"2. Is there any other way to assign prototype?"* yep: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just another technique.

```
A.prototype = B.prototype;
```

By doing this, any changes to the `B` prototype will also change the `A` prototype because they’re the
same object, and that’s bound to have undesirable side effects.

```
 A.prototype = new B();
```

Using this , we're ALSO  Achieving inheritance with prototypes.

We make a `A` a `B` by making the `A` prototype an instance of `B`.

Example #1 :

```
function A() {  console.log("A!")}
function B() {  console.log("B!")}
A.prototype = new B();
a = new A();    
B.bb=function (){alert('');}
console.log(a.bb()) //Uncaught TypeError: Object #<B> has no method 'bb'
```

now look at this :

```
function A() {  console.log("A!")}
function B() {  console.log("B!")}
A.prototype = B.prototype;
a = new A();    
B.prototype.bb=function (){alert('');}
console.log(a.bb()) //does alert
```

Comment: In Google Chrome and in Firefox I have a instanceof B // true (in first case)

Comment: @yarix you're right. absolutly right. ( confused with `B`) . editing

Comment: @RoyiNamir, your example makes no sense. in the first case, B.bb is not available even when you create an instance of B class. You've just created a static bb function of B type, that's all. The answer of Andrey is more correct. The difference is, in one case you inherit only methods, in the 2nd case you inherit both, state and functionality.

Comment: @Alexandr did you understand my answer ?  In the first example I'm trying to show that even if you add props to the B function  , it doesn't recognize it. as opposed to the second example where if I set B.proto.bb - then the change is visible

Comment: @RoyiNamir,your example, as I understand it does not show the difference between A.prototype = new B(); and A.prototype = B.prototype; it is more about: B.bb=function (){alert('');} vs B.prototype.bb=function (){alert('');}. The first function is not visible anyway and it does not matter how A.prototype is defined.
Change in your first example: A.prototype = new B(); line onto: A.prototype = B.prototype; like in the 2nd example. the console output of the 1st example will not change, you get the same error.

Comment: @RoyiNamir what you are showing is just function definition via prototype vs static functions in JS, that's all:
function B(){}
B.bb = function(){}
var obj = new B();
b.bb(); 
You cannot invoke bb via b instance of B.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add something to B and you'll get the difference:

```
function A() {
  console.log("A!")
}

function B() {
  this.text = "aaa";
}
```

You will have:

```
// First case
A.prototype = B.prototype;
a = new A();  

// a --> {}


// Second case
A.prototype = new B();
a = new A();  // a instanceof A,B

// a --> { text="aaa" }
```

Comment: If I'll call B.apply(this); in A's constructor it will become the same?

Comment: I thought you want A to be a prototype of B, why should you make a call to B inside A's constructor?

Comment: I've found that it is working like a call `super()` in Java. So it helps to inherit the properties of the super class.

Answer (score 0):

@Iaroslav Karandashev, the difference is in one case you inherit only functionality

```
A.prototype = B.prototype;
```

In another case you inherit both, state and functionality.

```
A.prototype = new B();
```

You may change slightly the first case, in order to have the same behavour:

```
// First case
function B() {
  console.log("B!")
}
//child:
function A() {
  console.log("A!")
  //invoke parent constructor:
  B.apply(this);
}

A.prototype = B.prototype;
a = new A();  // a instanceof A,B


// Second case
function B() {
  console.log("B!")
}
//child, you do not need to invoke constructor of base class:
function A() {
  console.log("A!")
}
//base class constructor is invoked here:
A.prototype = new B();
a = new A();  // a instanceof A,B
```