# Confusing JS prototyping and OOP with instance variables

Tags: javascript, variables, prototype, instance, instance-variables

So I would like to say I understand JavaScript fairly well, but it seems that the language always likes to throw a wrench at me.  I have a problem (well maybe not problem, but for sure confusion) on the behavior of "instance" variables for JS objects.  Lets take a look at the following code

```
function A(a) {
    this.a = a;  
    this.b = [];
}
function B(a) {
   //A.apply(this, arguments);
    this.a = a
}
B.prototype = new A();
B.prototype.constructor = B;
B.prototype.append = function(b) {
    this.b.push(b);  
};

var one = new B("one");
var two = new B("two");
console.log(one.a);
console.log(two.a);
one.append(10);
console.log(one.b);
console.log(two.b);
```

If you run this code, you will see that `one.b` and `two.b` have shared the same `b` "instance" variable array.  I have only noticed this happening on arrays.  I understand that if this was `A.prototype.b = []`, that it would definitely be shared across all instances of `A` or its children.  What I don't understand is that it is defined with 'this' command, which means it should be per instance.  The interesting thing is that if you uncomment the `A.apply(this, arguments)` (effectively calling super on the parent) and remove `this.a = a` inside the `B` constructor, it works as you think it would.  Would anyone know the reason why this is happening?

Comment: Mutating shared members that are on the prototype. Explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 you should not create an instance of parent to set the prototype part of inheritance. You'll have instance specific values of parent on child prototype (shared by child instances) even if you un comment the apply and shadow these members they are still there on the prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem here has to do with the `prototype` property of Functions, versus the `[[Prototype]]` hidden property of objects. I'm not sure if any implementations actually *use* that name for the hidden property -they don't have to, because it's hidden- but some implementations use the non-standard name `__proto__` to make it accessible to the script code. I'm going to use this name, even though it's non-standard, to make the distinction clearer between the two; you'll see why in a moment.

The `new` operator does a couple of things here. First, it creates a new object and sets its `__proto__` to the `prototype` property of the function that it's about to call. Then it calls that function, with the new object set to `this`.

In other words, you didn't define `this.b` with the `this` keyword. You defined it all the way back when you created `B.prototype`. The result of creating your object `one` looks something like this:

```
{
    "a" : "one",
    "__proto__" : {
        // This is a reference to B.prototype, which was created with your call to new A()
        "a" : undefined /* because your call to new A() didn't have any arguments */,
        "b" : [],
        "constructor" : /* reference to B() */,
        "append" : /* reference to the append() function you defined */,
        "__proto__" : undefined /* this would reference A.prototype if you had defined one */
}
```

See the extra `a` and `b` on your `__proto__`? Those were created when you called `new A()` to define `B.prototype`. The `a` isn't likely to do much of anything, because it's behind another `a` in the prototype chain, so things seem to work well enough (most of the time). But that `b` is another matter, because it isn't behind anything.

When your call to `B.prototype.append` references `this.b`, it first looks at the root level of the object for a `b` property, and it doesn't find one (because you never defined it). But your object has a `__proto__`, so it looks there for a `b`: this is called the *prototype chain*. And it finds one, so it appends to that array. Because all the objects you create with `new B()` share a reference to that same object, this gets shared among all the different members.

Let's swap the comments around the way you mentioned. What does the object look like now?

```
{
    "a" : "one",
    "b" : [],
    "__proto__" : {
        // This is a reference to B.prototype, which was created with your call to new A()
        "a" : undefined /* because your call to new A() didn't have any arguments */,
        "b" : [],
        "constructor" : /* reference to B() */,
        "append" : /* reference to the append() function you defined */,
        "__proto__" : undefined /* this would reference A.prototype if you had defined one */
}
```

Do you see the difference? Because `A()` actually got a chance to run on `this` during the call to `new B()`, it put a `b` at the root of the object, and this one belongs to only that object: it's not part of any `__proto__` or anything. You've still got that shared `b` hanging back in the prototype chain, but it's got another `b` in front of it now, so `B.prototype.append()` will never see it. It'll find the instance-specific `b` first, and that's why your second example works the way you intended.

One last point. Those shared `a` and `b` properties back in the prototype chain aren't really doing you any good: in this particular code, they don't do anything but take up space. It IS possible for code to make use of them, but that doesn't suit your use case, so it would be best to get rid of them.

How do you do that? You have to do it without actually calling `A()`, because that would set the `a` and `b` properties back in the prototype chain, and you don't want that, but this means you can't use `new A()`. But there's another way to create objects that does what you want: the `Object.create` function. You pass it the object that you want to become the `__proto__` of the new object, so it looks like this:

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;
```

I usually wrap this rigamarole up in a function, like so:

```
Object.subclass = function (sub, sup) {
    sub.prototype = Object.create(sup.prototype);
    sub.prototype.constructor = sub;
}
```

Once I've got that, I can just call `Object.subclass(B, A)`, which is a pretty clear representation of what I want. It does mean that I have to call `A()` in the constructor for `B()`, just like you describe, but the resulting object doesn't have the extra junk from calling `new A()` earlier in the process.

Comment: Super awesome explanation.  It helps better explain what the first comment was getting to.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing `B.prototype = new A();` which is equivalent to

```
B.prototype.a = undefined;
B.prototype.b = [];
// or actually
// B.prototype = {a: undefined, b: []};
```

That's where the shared array comes from.

You are not calling the `A` constructor for each instance of `B`. Uncomment the `A.apply(this, arguments);` line and it will work as expected.

See [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196) for a better way to setup inheritance.

Comment: If that is the case, then why doesn't `one.a` and `two.a` both equal to `"two"`?  

Lets look at this:

`function A() {
    this.a = "hi";  
    this.b = [];
}
function B() {
}
B.prototype = new A();
B.prototype.constructor = B;
B.prototype.append = function(b) {
    this.b.push(b);  
};
B.prototype.name = function(a) {
    this.a = a;  
};

var one = new B();
var two = new B();
one.name("one");
two.name("two");
console.log(one.a);
console.log(two.a);
one.append(10);
two.append(20);
console.log(one.b);
console.log(two.b);`

Comment: dude, that one made my eyes bleed.

Comment: @zero: because you are **assigning** to `this.a` which always creates (or updates) property on the object itself (whether it exists on the prototype or not). `this.b.push(...)` is not assigning, it's **reading** `this.b` and **mutates** the result (the array). In this process, `b` is looked up in the prototype chain.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense then.  So either make sure to do A.apply, or don't define the array in the super class, but in the subclass.  Thanks