# Any benefits to having a reference to parent prototype in javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, polyfills

We're all familiar with the following polyfill to create objects in JavaScript:

```
function inherit(C, P) {
    var F = function () {};
    F.prototype = P.prototype;
    C.prototype = new F();
}
```

One downside of this is that you will not have access to the parent's own members. Child instances will only have access to the prototype chain.

So I think the best inheritance solution is as follows:

```
var inherit = (function () {
  var F = function () {};
  return function (C, P) {
    F.prototype = P.prototype;
    C.prototype = new F();
    C.prototype.constructor = C;
  }
}());

function Parent(a){
    this.a = a;
}

Parent.prototype.a_proto = function(){return "a_proto";}

function Child(a,b){
    Parent.apply(this,[a]);
    this.b = b;
}

inherit(Child, Parent);

var c = new Child("a","b");
console.log(c.a); // a
console.log(c.b); // b
console.log(c.a_proto()); // a_proto
delete c.a;
console.log(c.a); // undefined
```

The reason why I like the above solution is because first you use the `apply` function to copy the parent's own members to the child's own members, therefore allowing true inheritance of the parent's own members. Second, the child also has a link to the prototype chain, and can therefore inherit prototype properties of the parent…and since we use a proxy, the child cannot modify the parent's prototype.

I was also introduced to the concept of an uber method in the book *JavaScript Patterns*. Basically, in the uber method the author says we "add a reference to the original parent". This is like having access to the superclass in other languages and could be handy on occasion." Here's the implementation:

```
function inherit(C, P) {

  var F = function () {};

  F.prototype = P.prototype;

  C.prototype = new F();

  C.uber = P.prototype;

}
```

I don't see how adding a reference to the original parent is good. Now the child is able to modify the parent's prototype, which is a bad thing. What is this person talking about, we now have access to superclass like in other languages? I thought using `apply` and the prototype chain already has given access to the superclass. Are there really any benefits to having a reference to the parent's prototype?

Comment: Imagine that you override an instance method of `Parent` using `Child.prototype.xxx = ...`. How would you call the super method without a direct reference to `Parent` or `Parent.prototype`?

Comment: I'm not sure which new element you introduced here. If it is `Parent.apply(this,[a]);`, then yes, you should absolutely do that. It's like calling `super()` in Java or ES6 for example. The typical way to setup inheritance is setting the prototype via `Object.create(Parent.prototype)` and calling the parent constructor in the child constructor. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17393153/218196 .

Comment: @FelixKling my question was about "C.uber = P.prototype;"

Comment: Ah... I don't see any particular use of this, since `Child` has a reference to `Parent` anyway. The child is able to modify `Parent.prototype` already. Not that it's a good thing, but adding `uber` doesn't make it better or worse.

Comment: @FelixKling you are right I do have a reference to parent. But as RobW stated in first comment, if I override an instance of Parent using Child.prototype.xxx, I will no longer have that reference to parent, no?

Comment: Via `Parent.prototype.xxx.call(this);`. You don't need `uber`. It just might be less to type.