# Javascript not inheriting prototype properties

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Why won't Javascript inherit the properties from a prototype

**Example**

```
function Man(name,age,color){
this.name = name;
this.age = age;
this.color = color;
}

boy = function Boy(){};

boy.prototype = new Man();

myboy = new boy('hari',14,'blue');

console.log(myboy); 
// => myboy {name:undefined, age:undefined, color:undefined}
```

It does not inherit the properties.

**Its meant to have the properties**

```
// => myboy {name:'hari', age:14, color:'blue'}
```

Comment: *"It does not inherit the properties."* Uhm, yes it does, it clearly has `name`, `age` and `color`. They just don't have any values because you are calling `Man` without any arguments, and `Boy` doesn't do anything with the arguments you provided.

Comment: It's inheriting the prototype. Not the constructor.

Comment: Yes your right. I'll edit my question. Why does it not inherit the values of the properties.

Comment: As I said: *"`Boy` doesn't do anything with the arguments you provided."* The function is empty.

Comment: Ok I understand. Can I inherit the constructor of Man?
So I won't have to write the constructor every time I inherit a prototype

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It does not inherit the properties.

Yes it does, it clearly has `name`, `age` and `color`. They just don't have any values because you are calling `Man` without any arguments, and `Boy` doesn't do anything with the arguments you provided.

Your inheritance setup is simply incorrect. You should add the parent prototype to the prototype chain of the child using `Object.create`:

```
Boy.prototype = Object.create(
  Man.prototype,
  {constructor: {value: Boy, writable: true}}
);
```

And, like in other languages, you have to *call the parent constructor* inside the child constructor (applied to the new child instance), passing along all the needed argumants:

```
function Boy(name, age, color) {
  Man.call(this, name, age, color);
}
// or
function Boy() {
  Man.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

---

More info:

- [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196)
- [Inheritance revisited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited)