# javascript. References problems. Inheritance. Scope This

Tags: javascript

Look my problem:

I have a class that look like this:

```
var els=[];
var base = function(){
    this.config = {}
}


var X1 = function(){
}
X1.prototype = new base();
X1.prototype.indexme = function(i){
    this.config.index = i;
}
X1.prototype.add = function(){
    var i = els.push(this)
    this.indexme(i)
}

var teste = new X1();
teste.add();
var teste2 = new X1();
teste2.add();
var teste3 = new X1();
teste3.add();

console.log(els)
```

Why this.config.index is overwritten to another instances?

I expected that teste have config.index = 1; teste2 config.index= 2 and teste3 config.index=3

Thanks

Comment: What is `this.teste(i)`? Also, you're inheriting the whole `config` object. It's always the same object.

Comment: You're pushing the X1 Object onto els, so the index won't be be a number.

Comment: I think `X1.prototype.test` should be `X1.prototype.teste` = bad edit

Comment: Why do you guys downvote? I don't think this is a naive question. This.config references to the X1.prototype.config, and all instances of X1 will share the same prototype, so teste1, teste2 and teste3 will get the same result for config.index

Comment: @wander i dont know too. I have a doubts and i lost a day to solve my problem. I think that when you inherit to a class, the base properties should be a model to another classes but no references. Each class it should be a new parent instance.

Comment: Prototype is attached to the class definition, so you can treat prototype as a static property of class. Then clearly, every instance of a certain class will share the same prototype.

Comment: Here is a better way to setup inheritance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196

Comment: @FelixKling for me this make more sense. Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype); This approach do exactly what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All instances of `X1` share the same prototype, which is an instance of `base` with a `config` property. Thus, all instances of `X1` share the same `config` property. You can move the line `this.config = {};` to the `X1` constructor or you can define an `init()` function in `base` that assigns `this.config` for each object and call `init()` from the `X1` constructor.

Comment: The idea is only the Base be a model to my another classes, if i do a copy of this.config in init of another classes is a bad solution?

Comment: More one doubt. If i do : this.config = {index: var} all of my instances get the correct values.

Why this.config.index get the same values? In theory this.config already have references in the prototype? Or the simple fact that i do an attribution clean the references?

Comment: When you assign a `config` property to `this`, it hides the same property in the prototype, but the prototype property is still there.