# Safely inheriting prototypes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Let's say I'm shooting for some basic inheritance in my application, I could achieve this by setting the prototype of my child to the parent.

```
// Parent "class"
var Car = function(year) {
    this.year = year;
};

Car.prototype.drive = function() {
    console.log('Vrooom');
};

// Child "class"
var Toyota = function() {
    Car.apply(this, arguments);
};

Toyota.prototype = Car.prototype;

var myCar = new Car(2010), myToyota = new Toyota(2010);

myCar.drive(); // Vrooom
myToyota.drive(); // Vrooom
```

Seems to work, but is obviously bad because if I set a new method on my `Toyota.prototype`, it will be set on `Car`'s prototype.

```
Toyota.prototype.stop = function() {
    console.log('stooop');
};

myCar.stop(); // stooop  <--- bad
myToyota.stop(); // stooop  <--- good
```

To solve this, instead of `Toyota.prototype = Car.prototype;` I can add an intermediary:

```
var ctor = function() { };
ctor.prototype = Car.prototype;

Toyota.prototype = new ctor();

Toyota.prototype.stop = function() {
    console.log('stooop');
};

myCar.stop(); // throws undefined error  <--- good
myToyota.stop(); // stooop  <--- good
```

But I don't understand why this works.  `ctor` creates a new instance with its prototype set to `Car's` prototype, and then `Toyota` sets its prototype to that new instance.

But why create an empty object with a prototype that gets referenced by `Toyota`'s prototype?
Why doesn't setting a new method on `Toyota` set it on `Car` like it does in the first example?
What if I want several layers of inheritance, it seems like I need to glue them together with a `new ctor` every time?

Comment: Maybe the following answer will be helpful to you, it covers constructor functions, prototype, inheritance and mix ins: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: @spender You mean `Toyota.prototype = Object.create(Car.prototype)` don't you? It's better not to create an instance of Parent to be used as prototype of Child.

Comment: @HMR: Yes, I deleted my answer because it became clear that my knowledge of inheritance in JS is somewhat flawed. Forgot to delete the comment too.

Comment: @HMR Great post, thanks for writing it and pointing me to it.

Comment: Another reference: [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why create an empty object with a prototype that gets referenced
>   by **Toyota**'s prototype?

Because if you do this: `Toyota.prototype = new Car();`

Now **Toyota**'s prototype is an instance of **Car**, which means that in addition to having **Car**'s prototype in the chain, it also has any properties set in the **Car** constructor itself. Basically you wouldn't want **Toyota.prototype** to have a property called `year` like so: `Toyota.prototype.year`. Because of this it's a lot better to have an empty constructor like so:

```
var ctor = function() { };
ctor.prototype = Car.prototype;

Toyota.prototype = new ctor();
```

Now **Toyota.prototype** has the `new ctor()` instance as it's prototype, which in turn has `Car.prototype` in its own chain. This means that instances of **Toyota** now can execute methods that exist in **Car.prototype**.

> Why doesn't setting a new method on **Toyota** set it on **Car** like it does
>   in the first example?

With this: `Toyota.prototype = Car.prototype;` you're setting Toyota' prototype to be the same exact object as what `Car.prototype` contains. Since it is the same object, changing it in one place also changes it everywhere else. This means that objects are passed be reference and not by value, which is another way of saying that when you assign an object to 3 different variables, it is the same object regardless of which variable you use. Strings for example are passed by value. Here is an example with strings:

```
var str1 = 'alpha';
var str2 = str1;
var str3 = str1;

str2 = 'beta';

// Changing str2 doesn't change the rest.
console.log(str1); //=> "alpha"
console.log(str3); //=> "alpha"
console.log(str2); //=> "beta"
```

Now compare to objects and their properties;

```
var obj1 = {name: 'joe doe'};
var obj2 = obj1;
var obj3 = obj1;

console.log(obj1.name); //=> "joe doe"
console.log(obj2.name); //=> "joe doe"
console.log(obj3.name); //=> "joe doe"

obj2.name = 'JOHN SMITH';

console.log(obj1.name); //=> "JOHN SMITH"
console.log(obj2.name); //=> "JOHN SMITH"
console.log(obj3.name); //=> "JOHN SMITH"
```

> What if I want several layers of inheritance...

Here is another way of creating layers of inheritance:

```
var Car = function(year) {
    this.year = year;
};

Car.prototype.drive = function() {
    console.log('Vrooom');
};

var Toyota = function() {
    Car.apply(this, arguments);
};

// `Object.create` does basically the same thing as what you were doing with `ctor()`
// Check out the documentation for `Object.create` as it takes a 2nd argument too.
Toyota.prototype = Object.create(Car.prototype);


// Create instances
var 
  myCar = new Car(2010), 
  myToyota = new Toyota(2010);


// Add method to Toyota's prototype
Toyota.prototype.stop = function() {
    console.log('stooop');
};
```

Let's try it out now:

```
myToyota.stop(); //=> 'stooop'
myCar.stop(); //=> 'TypeError: undefined is not a function'

myCar.drive(); //=> Vrooom
myToyota.drive(); //=> Vrooom
```

Comment: Thank you!  This all made sense and you were the only one not telling me to just set it to an instance of `new Car()` :D

Comment: I deleted my answer to this... +1

Comment: It's better to not use create an instance of Parent to set as prototype of Child. Parent may have instance specific members that should not be on Child.prototype or when you're defining Child you can't create an instance of Parent because it depends on a certain application state that the application hasn't reached yet at the point of defining Child. Use Object.create instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the following line:

`Toyota.prototype = Car.prototype;`

and then later modifying this object:

```
Toyota.prototype.stop = function() {
    console.log('stooop');
};
```

because in the first line, you set `Toyota.prototype` to the exact same object as `Car.prototype`. *This is not a copy, it is a reference to the same object!* So as soon as you modify `stop` on `Toyota.prototype`, you actually modify both `Toyota.prototype` and `Car.prototype`, because it is one and the same.

What you'd really want to do is replacing the first line with:

`Toyota.prototype = Object.create(Car);`

so that you now have the prototype of `Toyota` point to the `Car` function, as it should, instead to `Car`'s own `prototype`. Congratulations, you've used the prototype chain!
(Note: Using `Object.create` to do class inheritance is inherently more stable and reliable, because it does not run any code that you might have contained in the `Car` function, but only sets up the prototype link.)

For further discussion on what is happening here exactly, and why you might be better off *not* using "class inheritance" in JS at all, you might want to read [Chapters 4-6 of You Don't Know JS (objects & prototypes)](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch4.md).

On your last question: "What if I want several layers of inheritance, it seems like I need to glue them together with a new ctor every time?" – yes, you'd need to do this, and this is the standard pattern for (fake) classes and inheritance in JavaScript.

Comment: It's better to not use create an instance of Parent to set as prototype of Child. Parent may have instance specific members that should not be on Child.prototype or when you're defining Child you can't create an instance of Parent because it depends on a certain application state that the application hasn't reached yet at the point of defining Child. Use Object.create instead.

Comment: It's better to not use these "class" constructs at all, and use `Object.create` in all places. But that is indeed true.

Comment: So you suggest not using constructor functions? By any chance; did you get that from Douglass Crockford? You do know that he has yet to produce the correct code for "classical inheritance"? How would you go about initializing instance specific members and what exactly is so bad about constructor functions?

Comment: This discussion doesn't really belong here; but no, I did not get this from Crockford, I didn't even read his book. You can read up on why class inheritance in JS is suboptimal in [YDKJS Chapters 4-6](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch4.md).

Comment: Tank you for your reply. Still don't get the benefits of using chapter 6 patterns over constructor functions. Other than liking the syntax better than the confusion constructor functions I can't see an obvious technical advantage.