# Inherited class not getting its own methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

```
function Mammal(name){
   this.name = name;
}
Mammal.prototype.displayName = function(){
   return this.name;
}

function Organism(name){
   this.orgName = name;
}
Organism.prototype.print = function(){
    return this.orgName;
}

Organism.prototype = new Mammal();  //Organism inherits Mammal

//Testing
var o = new Organism('Human');

o.print()
```

This comes as undefined. Why? this should show since it is a method of class Organism.
 print() does not show up in the object

Comment: *"This comes as undefined."* Can't repro, I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. Also have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196) to learn how to set up inheritance properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
Organism.prototype = new Mammal();  //Organism inherits Mammal
```

you replace the entire `prototype` object, thus wiping out the previously assigned:

```
Organism.prototype.print = function(){
    return this.orgName;
}
```

---

You can fix it by changing the order so you "add" your new method to the inherited prototype:

```
function Organism(name){
   this.orgName = name;
}

Organism.prototype = new Mammal();  //Organism inherits Mammal

Organism.prototype.print = function(){
    return this.orgName;
}
```

---

FYI as an aside, you should be thinking about using `Organism.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype);` instead and you should be calling the constructor of the base object too.  See [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for examples.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign

```
Organism.prototype = new Mammal();
```

you are clobbering the Organism.prototype object that had the print function on it.  Try this instead for your inheritance:

```
function Mammal(name){
   this.name = name;
}
Mammal.prototype.displayName = function(){
   return this.name;
}

function Organism(name){
   this.orgName = name;
}

Organism.prototype = Object.create(Mammal.prototype);
Organism.constructor = Mammal;

// or _.extend(), if using underscore
jQuery.extend(Organism.prototype, {
     print: function(){
        return this.orgName;
    }
});

//Testing
var o = new Organism('Human');

o.print()
```

Comment: This not a jQuery question by any tag, so why are you using jQuery?

Comment: Cause it's the cat's pajamas.  My use of $.extend() isn't really necessary for the answer.  Just my preference.  `Organism.prototype.print = function(){}` is fine too.

Comment: The use of *$* as a function identifier is not unique to jQuery in the same way that *\_* is not unique to underscore.js so you should name the library you are using if you use one.

Comment: Your indentation on the print function is off by 1.