# javascript object inheritance - subclass and superclass

Tags: javascript, oop

Whats the difference between these two approaches?

## First approach

```
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
    Shape.call(this);
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();
```

## Second approach

```
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
    Shape.call(this);
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = new Shape();

var rect = new Rectangle();
```

Comment: Main disadvantage of the second approach is that it requires one more extra invocation of `new Shape`. This can be avoided with intermediate empty function, but anyway pattern #1 is preferred.

Comment: Also, `Object.create` is only copying `Shape.prototype` over to `Rectangle.prototype`. If you set `Rectangle.prototype` to `new Shape()`, it will also have the privileged values `x` and `y` in its prototype, which you probably don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two differences: one big, one small.

**The small difference is that in the second approach, `Rectangle` prototypes won't have their `constructor` property set properly**. It will point to `Shape`, rather than `Rectangle`. This is an extremely common mistake in JavaScript OO approaches, and most of the time you can get away with it because people don't use the `constructor` property for very much, but it's there.

**The big difference is the additional call to `Shape()` in the second constructor**. In your particular example, things work out more or less OK: `Rectangle.prototype` has some extra properties (`x` and `y`, both of which equal zero) that you probably didn't intend for it to have, but these will get overshadowed by the corresponding properties in your `Rectangle` instances anyway. Again, the kind of extremely common but tiny bug that works often enough that you can get away with it.

**The problem with the second method is that it only works when the superclass constructor doesn't need any arguments**. Your example happens to fit that description, because all it does is initialize certain properties to default values. But there exist use cases where that setup isn't really appropriate, and the second method can't be used in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

The primary difference is that in the second approach, the `Shape` constructor is called only once. In the first approach, the `Shape` constructor is not called, instead `Object.create(Shape.prototype)` creates a new object from the prototype. The parent constructor can then be called once per child construction with `Shape.call`.

You can still call `Shape.call` for each subclass, as in the second approach, but it results in an extra call to the constructor during the initial prototype creation.

Also, using the first approach with `Object.create` causes the `constructor` property of the `prototype` to be overwritten, so `Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;` is used to reset the `constructor` property.

Comment: actually, with the second approach, the way its written, the Super constructor gets called twice, once by new'ing it and second by Shape.call

Comment: @nuway I noticed that and made and of it.

Comment: great way to power phrase my answer btw

Comment: @nuway I didn't read your answer until after I finished mine.

Answer (score 1):

Main disadvantage of the second approach is that it requires one more extra invocation of `Shape` constructor in order to create an object to be used as prototype for `Rectangle`. There are different way to avoid it, for example with intermediate empty function:

```
function Rectangle() {
    Shape.call(this);
}

function f() {}
f.prototype = Shape.prototype;

Rectangle.prototype = new f();
```

As you can see, this is obviously very clumsy.

For this reason patter #1 using `Object.create` is preferred as more convenient and efficient.

However note that both snippets have another problem: own properties are copied with `Shape.call(this);` which is again can be undesirable.

Comment: What do you mean by.. "own properties are copied with Shape.call(this); which is again can be undesirable."

Comment: `Shape.call(this)` serves the only purpose - create own properties of the `Rectangle` instance object. Basically this line invokes `Shape` in context of the `Rectangle` which makes it gain own properties defined in `Shape`. But the problem is that parent constructor function may perform operations that are not desirable to be executed when `Rectangle` instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

Object.create does not execute the constructor.

calling with New is  equivalent to Object.create(object.prototype) + running the constructor function.

Comment: Not quite, the `constructor` property will be different if you use `Object.create` then manually call the `constructor` on the object (sorry I deleted this the first time, I was double-checking something).

Comment: Object.create(object.prototype) , we need to set back the constructor property? but basically it doesnt impact any thing

Comment: Could this line be omitted? `Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;` What does it do?!

Comment: refer to my answer on this post @clarkk 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159784/in-javascript-inheritance-via-b-prototype-new-a-why-does-one-need-to-set-b-p/28159807#28159807

Comment: if you do new Rectangle() it will still run rectangle orignal function but  Rectangle.protoype.constructor() will call Shape() @clarkk

Answer (score -1):

the biggest practical difference is that when you use new, the super class's constructor will be invoked, without need for `Shape.call(this);`.

Comment: Probably someone found your answer hard to understand. Maybe you need to expand it a little.