# Prototypical inheritance using Object.create for prototype gives [Object] as prototype of an instance

Tags: javascript

It's been advised that `Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);` is preferable to `Derived.prototype = new Base();` (like in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393153/968155)).

That makes sense, but when I use this approach, like so:

```
function B(){};
B.prototype.doA = function(){};

function D(){};
D.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype);

var d = new D();

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(d));
```

it outputs `Object {doA: function}` to the console, and logging `console.log(d)` shows an object with `__proto__: Object`. Why is it not `D {doA: function}`?

Everything else seem to work:

```
d.doA();
d instanceOf D; // true
d instanceOf B; // true
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34nzn9sp/)

It seems weird. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Probably only weirdness of `console.log`. Try to set `D.protype.constructor = D;` and see whether the output changes.

Comment: @Bergi, I think you are right. I was trying it in Chrome and it changed it to `D {constructor: function, doA: function}`. IE just shows [object Object] regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/czmj2r12/)***

When you use the `Object.create` approach, it is typically paired with a constructor assignment as well.

```
//...
D.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype);
D.prototype.constructor = D;
//...
```

Comment: This kinda "works", but now adds `constructor` property to the output, which I guess is always there but hidden. So, is this an artifact of how console works?

Comment: @NewDev - The constructor property should always be part of the output for instances of functions. When you use Object.create it only copies the prototype and that is why the constructor is simply object. For example, if you look at using `var d = new B();` in the fiddle, you will see that the log in the console includes the constructor property equal to function B

Comment: It actually didn't for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/gfpq8c2a/1/. But seeing how IE doesn't show any kind identifier at all, it seems like it is just a console implementation issue.

Comment: @NewDev - You are only logging the object in your fiddle, which is different than the other scenarios. That is why it does not show up. http://jsfiddle.net/gfpq8c2a/2/