# Difference between creating inheritance using object.create and new operator

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Please find my two methods of creating inheritance. Can some one explain me what going on with each type.

**Method 1:**

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
}

function Employee(name, designation){
    Person.call(this, name);
   this.designation = designation;
}

Employee.prototype = new Person();
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;

Employee.prototype.getDesignation = function(){
    return this.designation;
}

new Employee("Jagadish", "Cons");
```

[image]

**Method 2:**

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
}

function Employee(name, designation){
    Person.call(this, name);
    this. designation = designation;
}

Employee.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Employee.prototype.constructor = Employee;

Employee.prototype.getDesignation = function(){
    return this.designation;
}

new Employee("Jagadish", "Cons");
```

[image]

I have inserted the images of console of each object. In first method i can see **name property** in **Person class** which is undefined (refer first screenshot).

But in case of second method of inheritance i dont have **name property** in **Person class**.

Can someone explain in depth about this behavior and what is happening in background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing magical going on here, the program is doing exactly what it is told to do.

When you are calling `new Person`, you are creating a new object. That object has a `name` property because you are explicitly assigning to `this.name` inside the function.

`Object.create` however creates an *empty* object, unless it is passed a second argument with property descriptors.

---

To explain the specific difference between `Object.create` and `new A`:

`new A()`:

- Create a new object inheriting from `A.prototype`
- Apply `A` to the new object, i.e. call `A.call(newObj)`

`Object.create(A.prototype)`:

- Create a new object inheriting from `A.prototype`

So you see, the specific difference between those two calls is that with `new` the function is applied to the new object, with `Object.create` is isn't.

---

Related: [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i am still confused. I want to know how this statement Person.call(this, name);
is creating name property in Employee class

Comment: Are you just not familiar with what `call` does? It executes the function and sets its `this` value to the first passed argument. If you had `var obj = {}; Person.call(obj, 'foo');`, then the `name` property is set on `obj`.