# javascript constructor.prototype inheriting another constructor.prototype

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototype

Here is my problem:
Let`s say I have a constructor A() with prototype X;
And now I have another constructor B which I want to inherit from A.
So I have to do something like this: B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);

But why I just can`t call B.prototype = A.prototype since Object.create(A.prototype) it is eqaul to A.prototype?

Or instead of calling Object.create I can use a function like this:

```
function inherit(p) {
    function f(){};
    f.prototype = p;
    return new f();
}
```

and then `B.prototype = inherit(A.prototype)`.

What is the difference?
Why can`t call B.prototype = A.prototype?

Comment: Because to inherit you need to point the prototype to the constructor function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because if you add something to B.prototype you also will add to A.prototype

> But why I just can`t call B.prototype = A.prototype since
>   Object.create(A.prototype) it is eqaul to A.prototype?

If you do `B.prototype = A.prototype` then both prototypes will point to the same reference. If you do `B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype)` then `B.prototype` will take only the values from `A.prototype`, the reference won't be the same.

So,

```
B.prototype = A.prototype
B.prototype === A.prototype
// OUTPUT: true;

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype)
B.prototype === A.prototype
// OUTPUT: false;
```

**EDIT**

You can use the [generated typescript code example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Greeter%20%7B%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20GreeterPlus%20extends%20Greeter%20%7B%0A%7D) to extend without `Object.create`:

```
// b -> base class
// d -> new class
var __extends = function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
```

Comment: something like B.protoype.x = function(){} ?

Comment: Yes, it will cause A.prototype.x = function(){} too. Object.create will return a new Object.

Comment: So, in conclusion it`s all about the refrence...right?

Comment: Can I use something like:
`B.prototype = A.prototype; B.prototype = new B();`

or

`'for(prop in A.prototype) { B.prototype[prop] = A.prototype[prop]; }`
?

Comment: The short answer is no. If you do this, `new B() instanceof A` will return false. You can look at my edit for a complete solution without `Object.create`

Answer (score -1):

Because to inherit you need to point the prototype to the constructor function.
So you can do either one.

```
B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype)
```

Or

```
B.prototype = new A();
```

Comment: I know that I can do that, my problem was why not more simple...like B.prototype = A.prototype
because in order the  Object.create(A.prototype) will return a same object like A.prototype

Comment: As I already mentioned its the way Javascript inheritance works. The Object itself is used as template for inheritance. Also as explained by @wedney the way you doing is just pointing to same reference not implementing inheritance.

Comment: Yeah, but making abstraction of the refrence, there is no difference in assigning the prototype ...Its weird.

Comment: Take a look at this
B.prototype = A.prototype;
B.prototype = new B();
Now I can inherit from A without using Object.create, right?

Comment: No, you should not do `new A()` (or `new B()`) to create prototypes. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17393153/1048572)

Comment: But what about this
for(prop in A.prototype) {
 B.prototype[prop] = A.prototype[prop];
}