# using create vs prototype in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS.

I was experimenting in JSFiddle.

I have created an object A and then I have created two new Objects B and C like below.

```
debugger;
var A = {
    name:"h",
    lastname:'n',
    address:'B'
};
A.getname = function()
{
    console.log(this.name);
};
var B = Object.create(A);
var C=new Object();
C.prototype = A;
console.log(B.lastname);
console.log(C.lastname);
A.getname();
B.getname();
C.getname();
```

I have taken the concept of creating a new object with already existing object using Object.create(old object) from javascript:Good Parts book and the concept of inheriting object from http://www.codecademy.com/courses/objects-ii/3/3?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661 .

After debugging,
But I the value console.log(C.lastname) is undefined and C.getname() is giving me error.

```
TypeError: C.getname is not a function
```

Why is it throwing me error and what are the advantages of using Object.create() in this case.

Comment: Maybe the advantage of using `Object.create` is that it does work, while your `.prototype` code does not?

Comment: But I think the answer you're actually looking for is that `Object.create` is just what you use to inherit from an existing object, while `function C(){}; C.prototype = A;` and `var c = new C(); c.lastname; c.getname()` has the advantage of executing code to initialise instances.

Comment: @Bergi I believe the problem ( among others) is here `C.prototype = A;` the prototype he is referencing is not the one he needs. `C.constructor.prototype` is the one he's seeking. ( which I don't recommend)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Well he certainly is confusing constructor functions with instances for `C`.

Comment: @Bergi Is it even valid to do `Object.prototype=A;` ? doesn't work here. only if you manually add keys one by one (http://jsbin.com/dahuzu/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: [No, it's not](http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.3.1). You'll get an error in strict mode.

Comment: @RoyiNamir So this would be like Object.prototype=A as the object C is instance of Object()? and is this failing as Object.prototype=A is invalid?

Comment: @starkk92: Wait. What did you expect `C.prototype = A;` to do actually? Make `C` inherit from `A`?

Comment: @Bergi yes.I think Object.create() also does the same if I am not wrong.

Comment: @starkk92: Yes, `Object.create` does this. But `.prototype =` doesn't, that's an ordinary property assignment/creation! You'd need to use [`Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) instead.

Comment: see also the possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/9959727/1048572. `.prototype` is only used on constructor functions!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `.prototype` for inheritance, you'll need `A` and `C` to be classes (not just objects).

```
var A = function() {
    this.name = 'h';
    this.lastname = 'n';
    this.address = 'B';
}
A.prototype.getname = function() {
    console.log(this.name);
};
var a = new A(); 
console.log(a.getname()); // h

var C = function() {};
C.prototype = new A();
var c = new C();
console.log(c.lastname); // n
console.log(c.getname()); // h
```

One notable advantage of using [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) over [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) for inheritance is (as can be seen here) that with Object.create you can use simple objects (rather than classes).

To better understand advantages of using Object.create see @FelixKling's accepted answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392857/benefits-of-using-object-create-for-inheritance)...

Comment: In contrast, the notable advantage of using constructors+`.prototype` over `Object.create` is that they provide a means to initialise all instances on creation.