# extending init method without being recursive, javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extend functionality from using prototypes, but keep getting Maximum call stack size exceeded, basically, I'm doing this:

```
 var Parent = function() {};
 Parent.prototype.init = function(options){
    this.val_one = options.one;
    /*more init code*/
 };

var Child = function() {
   Parent.call(this);
};
Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;

Child.prototype.init = function(options) {
    this.val_two = options.two;
    //I also need val_one and all the initiation placed on the parent while keeping the init method name, (shadowing while extending?)

   Parent.prototype.init.call(this, options); 
   //will result in a self loop
   //copy all the method for adding a single extra value? is this the only way to do achieve this?
};
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;` is your problem. You are literally calling yourself.

Comment: it's not the same question, please read it again, I would appreciate if you remove the duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, it's not exactly the same question, but you said you'd appreciate *any* help - and I thought it would help you understanding what you got wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;
> ```

is your problem. You [must not use that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/1048572) for "inheritance" - it makes `Child` and `Parent` instances have *exactly* the same prototype object.

Morever, as you can test, `Parent.prototype.init === Child.prototype.init` - you've overwritten the original `init` method (the one you created using `Parent.prototype.init = function(options){…}`) on *that single object* in the assignment `Child.prototype.init = function(options) {…}`. So your "super" call is actually calling the method itself again, which leads to your unbound recursion.

Instead, use

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
```

and it will work as expected, as those are two distinct objects now.

Answer (score -1):

The init function you made is just another function , it is NOT the constructor and will not be called unless you call it within the constructor.

I made an example for you, hopefully this helps: https://jsfiddle.net/hfmbv98g/

```
var Parent = function(options) {
// constructor
this.val_one = options.one;
console.log("parent");
};

Parent.prototype.other_method = function() {
    console.log("Parent: other_method")
}

var Child = function(options) {
   Parent.call(this, options);
   this.val_two = options.two
   console.log("child");
};

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype); // See note below
Child.prototype.constructor = Child;


Child.prototype.other_method = function() {
    console.log("Child: other_method")
};
```

You should also read up on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, however, it does to match my needs, I'm aware of how the constructor works, my question is directly to shadowing a method keeping the parent and extending a new one (the child).