# Why Object.create doesn't create a new list for me?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a builder pattern in JavaScript. But I'm wondering why if I call `Object.create` twice I got the same list as before.

Here's my code.

```
var filterBuilder = {
  filters: [],
  addFilter: function(options) {
    var filter = { 
      'type': 'selector',
      'dimension': options.dimension,
      'value': options.value
    }
    this.filters.push(filter);
    return this;
  },
  build: function() {
    return this.filters;
  }
};
```

If I run `Object.create(filterBuilder).build()` I get `[]` which is good. But when I start adding filter

```
Object.create(filterBuilder).addFilter({dimension: '1', value: 'v'}).build();
```

I get one filter which is good

But then if I do

```
Object.create(filterBuilder).addFilter({dimension: '1', value: 'v'}).addFilter({dimension: '1', value: 'v'}).build();
```

I will get three filters, the first one is from the previous call. Isn't `Object.create` supposed to create a new object for me?

Comment: Because `filter` is a property of the prototype not the newly created object. All objects that inherit from that prototype, share that property. Similar case [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363094/understanding-prototypal-inheritance-methodologies-in-js/34363433)

Comment: `Object.create` does create a new empty object that inherits properties from `filterBuilder`. It does not create a new array or a `filters` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prototype properties are shared, so the `filters` array is the same for both objects you created. If you want each object to have its own `filters` you have to add it as an **own** property (a property that is owned by the object, not the prototype), ie:

```
var filterBuilder = {
  addFilter: function(options) {
    var filter = {
      'type': 'selector',
      'dimension': options.dimension,
      'value': options.value
    }
    this.filters.push(filter);
    return this;
  },
  build: function() {
    return this.filters;
  }
};

var a = Object.create(filterBuilder)
a.filters = [];
a.addFilter({dimension: '1', value: 'v'}).build();

var b = Object.create(filterBuilder)
b.filters = []
b.addFilter({dimension: '1', value: 'v'}).addFilter({dimension: '1', value: 'v'}).build();

console.log(a.filters.length, b.filters.length); // 1 2
```

You can do this with `new` as well:

```
function FilterContainer() {
  this.filters = [];
}

FilterContainer.prototype.addFilter = function() {
  ...
};

FilterContainer.prototype.build = function() {
  ...
};

// Has its own `filters` array
new FilterContainer().addFilter(...).build();
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. I read somewhere and I'm supposed to avoid using `new` I guess that only applies for inheritance?

Comment: It is ok advice, it depends. You can make your own thing with `Object.create`, I'd aim for something like `MyObject.new()`, this composes better than `new MyObject()`. But with ES6 `class` and the spread operator you avoid some of the confusion and unfamiliar syntax.

Comment: @toy: Yes, you should avoid `new` when creating prototype objects for subclasses that should inherit from another object. There's no reason to fear `new` anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Object.create(filterBuilder)` several times, you get two objects which hold references to the same `filters` array.

```
var b1 = Object.create(filterBuilder);
var b2 = Object.create(filterBuilder);

// now b1.filters is the _same_ object as b2.filters,
// so calling
b1.filters.push(...);

// will inevitably modify b2.filters as well.
```

Your best choice here is using classical functions and prototypes

```
function FilterBuilder() {
    this.filters = [];
}

FilterBuilder.prototype.addFilter = function() { };

var builder = new FilterBuilder();
builder.addFilter();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Object.create()` takes an optional second argument which can define properties that are not inherited from the prototype, so you can (re-)define the `filters` property of newly created object like this:

```
Object.create(filterBuilder, { 
  filters : { writable : true, enumerable: true, value : [] }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1m7xx4ge/2/

```
// full code

var filterBuilder = {
  filters: [],
  addFilter: function(options) {
    var filter = { 
      'type': 'selector',
      'dimension': options.dimension,
      'value': options.value
    }
    this.filters.push(filter);
    return this;
  },
  build: function() {
    return this.filters;
  }
};

Object.create(filterBuilder, { 
  filters : { writable : true, enumerable : true, value : [] }
})
.addFilter({dimension: '1', value: 'v'}).build();

Object.create(filterBuilder, { 
   filters : { writable : true, enumerable : true, value : [] }
})
.addFilter({dimension: '1', value: 'v'})
.addFilter({dimension: '1', value: 'v'}).build();
```