# Clarifications on prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I have a prototypal inheritance like below where `Student` extends `Guru`. I have three questions, can someone clarify the same.

```
function Guru(name){
  this.name = name;
}

Guru.prototype.copy = function(){
  return this.constructor(this.name);
}

function Student(name){
  Guru.call(this)
  this.name = name;
}

Student.prototype = Object.create(Guru.prototype);
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;
var stu = new Student("John Cena");

console.log(stu.constructor);
console.log(stu.__proto__);
```

1. Why should we avoid `Student.prototype = new Guru();`
2. What is the difference between these two:

   ```
   console.log(stu.constructor);
   console.log(stu.__proto__);
   ```

   Prints the below:

   ```
   [Function: Guru]
   Guru { constructor: [Function: Student] }
   ```
3. Difference between `constructor.prototype` and `prototype.constructor`? Do we have constructor.prototype in javascript?

Comment: Some brilliant answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work, especially the second answer. I'd also recommand reading an article about programming paradigms.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: Btw, the first question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here) and [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17393153/1048572?Benefits-of-using-Object.create-for-inheritance)

Comment: All your students are gurus? Wow. Btw, that `copy` method misses a `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why should we avoid `Student.prototype = new Guru()`?

Because `Guru` constructor expects an instance, not a subclass. Properties created in that constructor should be assigned directly to the instance.

In your case it doesn't matter much, but imagine this:

```
function C1() { this.o = []; }
function C2() {}
C2.prototype = new C1();
var c1a = new C1(), c1b = new C1(),
    c2a = new C2(), c2b = new C2();
c1a.o.push(123);
c2a.o.push(456);
c1b.o; // []    -- The property is NOT shared among C1 instances
c2b.o; // [456] -- The property is shared among all Sub instances
```

> 2. What is the difference between `stu.constructor` and `stu.__proto__`?

When you create the `Student` constructor, it receives automatically a `prototype` with a `constructor` property which points back to `Student`.

Instead , `__proto__` is a getter which returns the [[Prototype]] of an object. Note this is not much standard (it's only defined in an annex for browsers), you should use `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead.

Therefore, `stu.constructor` (inherited from `Student.prototype`) is `Student`. And `stu.__proto__` (inherited from `Object.prototype`) is `Student.prototype`.

> 3. Difference between `constructor.prototype` and `prototype.constructor`?

Using `constructor.prototype` on a prototype is pointless because it gives the same prototype (assuming it has not been altered).

Using `constructor.prototype` on a instance gives the prototype it inherits from (assuming it is not shadowed nor has been altered).

Using `prototype.constructor` on a constructor is pointless because it gives the same constructor (assuming it has not been altered).

Comment: @ShankarGuru Yes, usually that's undesirable.