# Using .prototype for adding method to variable

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to analyze this code and I'm having some trouble. My trouble starts with this line. `Customer.prototype = new Person();`. Now as far as i'm aware. We can add some methods to our variables like we did with `Person.prototype.getName`. Great, now `Person` has a `proto` pointed towards a function that returns a name. So what does it mean when we do `Customer.prototype = new Person();`. Does this mean that take all the methods and statements in `Person` and put them inside the variable `Customer`?

```
var Person = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
};

Person.prototype.getName = function() {
  return this.name;
};


var john = new Person("John");

//Try the getter
alert(john.getName());


Person.prototype.sayMyName = function() {
  alert('Hello, my name is ' + this.getName());
};

john.sayMyName();

var Customer = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
};


Customer.prototype = new Person();     


var myCustomer = new Customer('Dream Inc.');
myCustomer.sayMyName();


Customer.prototype.setAmountDue = function(amountDue) {
    this.amountDue = amountDue;
};
Customer.prototype.getAmountDue = function() {
    return this.amountDue;
};


myCustomer.setAmountDue(2000);
alert(myCustomer.getAmountDue());
```

Comment: in OOP tems it means that Customer inherits from Person

Comment: Don't put too much thought on it, [it's wrong anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17393153/1048572?Benefits-of-using-Object.create-for-inheritance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every object has a prototype, which is also an object.

When you do

```
Customer.prototype = new Person();
```

... you set the `Customer`'s prototype object. The methods and properties do not get copied into a `Customer` object, but when you reference a property/method on a `Customer`, the prototype chain is followed to find that property/method.

In the case of `myCustomer.sayMyName`, the JavaScript engine first looks in `myCustomer`'s owned properties, then in its prototype, which is a `Person` object, and then finally in the prototype of `Person` which is an object that has that method:

```
Person.prototype.sayMyName = function() {
  alert('Hello, my name is ' + this.getName());
};
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean they don't get copied but reference properties? Does that mean to say Customer can use everything Person has in it, but its not like the actual VALUE of Customer is being changed?

Comment: What do you mean with value? The only thing that changes in Customer is its prototype (its  `__proto__` property). All the rest is regulated by the JavaScript engine, which implements the prototype chain inheritance. And yes, the properties exposed by Person are available to Customer, unless Customer has its own implementation for them.

Comment: I see. So the properties exposed by Person are avaliable to Customer, but the opposite is surely not true?

Comment: Indeed, as you say.

Comment: Cool. Seriously this stuff seems so overly verbose, every documentation seems to explain this with such garbage wording.  Thanks

Comment: This is because JavaScript offers [more than one way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) to do it, which has led to a variety of programming styles, opinions, articles, ...

Comment: By the way, when I was studying through my book it says not to use the __proto__ to change stuff like this, and how its really bad. That being the case, should I think of __proto__ and prototype as the same thing?

Comment: underscore underscore proto underscore underscore for some reason it didnt show double underscore

Comment: Indeed, you probably shouldn't use `__proto__`. I just referred to that special property to indicate what changes when you assign to a constructor's `.prototype`. Note that you use `.prototype` on constructors (functions), while the object you instantiate with a constructor has the `__proto__` property which you normally should have no reason to access. I realise I should have written "a Customer object" in an above comment, where I just wrote "Customer". Sorry for the confusion that might have brought.

Comment: Thanks, you saved the day once again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116279/discussion-between-cresjoy-and-trincot).

Comment: Just had a question if you could respond when you are free :)

Answer (score 1):

By doing `Customer.prototype = new Person()` we are essentially doing class-inheritance as in another language. So, say we had:

```
var p = new Person();
Customer.prototype = p;
var c = new Customer();
```

The prototype (__proto__) of `c` is  `p` and the prototype of `p` is Person.prototype.

The naive way to do inheritance would be to `Customer.prototype = Person.prototype` which would make all instances of Customer share the same methods as Person. But, if we did `Customer.prototype.newMethod = ...`, it would also modify the prototype of `Person.prototype` (as they are the same object.

To allow a distinction between Customer prototype and Person prototype, we use `new Person()` instead as an intermediate in the chain which still has a link to the prototype of Person but is a separate object.

**Note:** Usually it is more conventional to do `Customer.prototype = Object.create(Person)` followed by `Customer.prototype.constructor = Customer;` because doing `new Person()` means that the constructor of `Person` is called (which is usually not wanted unless you are actually making a real object).

Comment: Please let me know if the following is correct: Say person has some properties. Perhaps it can return your full name. Now we do var p = new Person();. So P inherits all the properties from person. Now we say Customer.prototype = p;. Since P inherits everything from person, Customer now inherits everything from p, which inherited from Person. Now C inherits from Customer. Is that a good understanding?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. c inherits Customer.prototype and if p.fullname = 'john', then c.fullname will also be 'john' as c inherits the properties in p (as well as all those inherited by p itself).

Comment: thanks that helped. I need to learn a bit more before I delve a bit deeper. Looks like this material is quite deep.