# DRY JavaScript Inheritance from Within a Constructor

Tags: javascript, inheritance, design-patterns

Is it possible to get `Dog` and `Cat` to inherit from `Animal` (without using the `class` or `extends` keywords), without editing the code that has already been written, and **while keeping all new code within the current constructor functions**?

```
function Animal() {
  this.sleep = function() {
    var hoursSleepPerNight = this.hoursSleepPerNight;
    console.log( "z".repeat(hoursSleepPerNight) );
  }
}

function Dog() {
  this.hoursSleepPerNight = 8;
}

function Cat() {
  this.hoursSleepPerNight = 7;
}

var dog = new Dog();
dog.sleep();
// "zzzzzzzz"
```

Comment: `Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)`, but note that `sleep` is an own property, it won't be inherited. You could try `Dog.prototype = new Animal()` but be aware of side-effects.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Bergi, wishful thinking that JavaScript can be forced to behave like Python/Ruby I suppose.

Comment: It also seems unnatural to me that inheritance would be added *after* defining a "class"'s own methods and properties. I assumed there had to be a better way.

Comment: @Trajanson: Well you seem to have a solution already: `class`+`extends`, not different than in Python. Also you usually would define (prototype) methods *after* doing the inheritance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript uses prototypal inheritance, so you can inherit from `Animal` as follows:

```
function Animal() {
  this.sleep = function() {
    console.log("z".repeat(this.hoursSleepPerNight));
  }
}

function Dog() {
  this.hoursSleepPerNight = 8;
}
Dog.prototype = new Animal();
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;

function Cat() {
  this.hoursSleepPerNight = 7;
}
Cat.prototype = new Animal();
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;

var dog = new Dog();
dog.sleep();
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k0op9sb6/

If for some reason you must set the prototype within the constructor functions it looks like you may be able to use `Object.setPrototypeOf` or `__proto__` ([**proto**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)) -- **HOWEVER** this is universally **NOT RECOMMENDED**:

```
function Dog() {
  this.hoursSleepPerNight = 8;
  Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new Animal()); // this.__proto__ = new Animal();
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts on why `this.prototype = new Animal();` cannot be moved inside the Dog constructor?

Comment: Setting `this.prototype` adds an own property `prototype` to your instance.  This is not the same as setting Function.prototype.  It looks like you can get the behavior you are looking for by setting `this.__proto__` (updated above).

Comment: Please use [`Object.create(Animal.prototype)` instead of `new Animal`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17393153/1048572?Benefits-of-using-Object.create-for-inheritance) to do it properly, and use `Object.setPrototypeOf` instead of the deprecated `__proto__`.

Comment: @Bergi where does that line go? That was one of my original confusions. `Object.setPrototypeOf(Dog) = Object.create(Animal.prototype);` after the constructor does not work. `Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);` does not work #=> TypeError: dog.sleep is not a function

Comment: @Trajanson you should be able to replace `this.__proto__ = new Animal();` with `Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new Animal());` (updated above).  If you want your children objects to inherit the sleep method, however, setting the prototype with `Object.create(Animal.prototype)`  won't work since it's an own property. The typical javascript way of handling this would be to move your `sleep` function to the `Animal` prototype, and then have your children inherit as follows: `Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);` (not within your constructor function).

Comment: @lucasjackson: You should add a `Animal.call(this)` "super" call in the constructor anyway, then properties and privileged methods will be created as well.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible (and not sensible) to keep all inheritance-related code inside the constructor if you are looking for prototypical inheritance.