# Confusion With Javascript Inheritance

Tags: javascript, javascript-inheritance

I'm confused about javascript inheritance.

Consider the following code:

```
function parent(firstname, lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname || "abc";
    this.lastname = lastname || "def";
}

function child() {
   this.childname = "xys";
}
parent.prototype.Greetings = function () {
    alert("sayhi");
}
child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
var child1 = new child();
```

Now, does the `child1` object have access to the `firstname` and `lastname` properties?
I can access the `Greetings` method (because it's in the prototype).
If I try to access these, it is showing as `undefined`. 
What changes have to be made to access these variables?

Comment: Note: It's `Object.create`, not `object.create`.

Comment: Thanks @melpomene for the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What changes has to be done to access these variables?

You have to call the parent constructor in the child constructor:

```
function child() {
  parent.call(this);
  this.childname = "xys";
}
```

---

JavaScript "inheritance" is a lot less magical (i.e. implicit) than in other languages (before ES6 classes at least).

In your example you have a function `parent` which sets two properties on `this`. However, nowhere in your code are you calling `parent`, so these properties will never be set.

In order to set them we need to apply `parent` to the new `child` instance, which is done by calling `parent.call(this);`.

Since `parent` accepts arguments, you probably want to pass them through `child` eventually:

```
function child(firstname, lastname) {
  parent.call(this, firstname, lastname);
  this.childname = "xys";
}
```

---

Related: [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196)

Comment: Is this approach called as constructor stealing? .For inheritance, in javascript we should do a combination of prototypal and constructor stealing..Please correct me if iam wrong

Comment: @Geeky: I have never heard of that. But it's the same as calling `super()` in other languages (and ES6). Having to call the parent constructor is pretty typical for inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is using more recent ES2015 standards. The syntax is much clearer to follow. Do something like:

```
class Parent {
    constructor(firstname, lastname) {
        this.firstname = firstname || "abc";
        this.lastname = lastname || "def";
    }
    greetings() {
        alert("sayhi");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(){
        super(firstname, lastname);
        this.childname = "xys";
    }
}
var child1 = new child();
```

Info on ES2015 can be found at https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/ .
Also, more specifics on class declarations in javascript can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes .

Comment: This won't work, you have to call `super(this)` in the child constructor.

Comment: True, I had forgotten the `super(this)`. I updated the answer.

Comment: should be `constructor(firstname, lastname) {
   super(firstname, lastname)`

Comment: Oh whoops, yeah no need to pass this.

Comment: That's right, the arguments must be the same as for the parent constructor. Thanks. I'm a little new to js inheritance, as well.