# Working with Javascript Prototypes, and Scope

Tags: javascript

The first lesson is scope.

```
var scope = "global";
function Scope() {
    var scope = "local";
    this.s = function() { return scope; }
}
var instance = new Scope();
console.log(instance.scope); ///this is 'undefined' 
console.log(instance.s()); /// this is 'local'
```

This makes sense in the world of closures.

Then `BaseScope` is introduced.

```
function BaseScope() {
    this.scope = "parent";
    this.h = function() {return "Hello";}
}
Scope.prototype = Object.create(BaseScope);
```

So now, I want to add the prototype of `BaseScope` to `Scope`. The below, is what I **WANT** to be returned.

```
var instance2 = new Scope();
console.log(instance2.s()); ///Should be returning 'local' because it is the  fastest returned s() function on the object's prototype.
console.log(instance2.scope); ///Should be returning BaseScope's scope, since it is technically the only defined 'scope' property up the chain.
console.log(instance2.h()); ///Should return "Hello"
```

The last example is returning `undefined` which makes me think I am doing something completely wrong. What steps should I take to get the desired effect above?

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(instance2.scope);`?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek undefined

Comment: Your `BaseScope` is never called actually. `scope` property is never assigned to `instance2`. `BaseScope` function is also an object, that you want to treat as a prototype.

Comment: `Object.create(BaseScope)` gives you an object whose prototype object is the `BaseScope` **function**.

Answer (score 3):

You can access basescope on scope prototype as

scope.prototype=Object.create(BaseScope.prototype);

and if you want to have access to BaseScope's scope variable all you need is call BaseScope from Scope ,it can be done using BaseScope.call(this),using call you can change the scope of this .

check this snippet

```js
function Scope() {
  BaseScope.call(this);
  var scope = "local";
  this.s = function() {
    return scope;
  }
}

function BaseScope() {

  this.scope = "parent";
  this.h = function() {
    return "Hello";
  }
}
Scope.prototype = Object.create(BaseScope.prototype);

var instance = new Scope();
console.log(instance.scope); ///this is 'undefined' 
console.log(instance.s());
console.log(instance.h());
```

Comment: The line `Scope.prototype = Object.create( BaseScope.prototype);` seems unnecessary, since these objects do not deal with prototype chain at all.

Comment: How would I do this without putting `BaseScope.call(this)` into the `Scope()` definition

Comment: you cannot have access to BaseScope's variables without changing its context ...it cannot be done using call/apply...check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417710/confusion-with-javascript-inheritance

Comment: As OP wants to establish parent child relation ...which is inheritance i guess it can be done by setting their prototype