# javascript oop override inherited method

Tags: javascript, oop

```js
// The parent class
    var Parent = function (jqueryElement) {
        this.jqueryElement = jqueryElement;
    };
    
    Parent.prototype.attachClick = function () {
        var that = this;
         
        this.jqueryElement.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
    
            that.doClick($(this));
        });
    }
    
    Parent.prototype.doClick = function ($element) {
        console.info('click event from parent');
    }
    
    // First child class
    var A = function(jqueryElement) {
        var that = this;
    
        Parent.call(this, jqueryElement);
    
        // this is supposed to override the Parent's
        this.doClick = function ($element) {
            console.info('click event from A');
        };
    };
    
    A.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
    
    
    
    var test = new A($('.selector'));
    test.attachClick();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="selector">Click me</button>
```

At this stage, I'm supposed to see the message `"click event from A"`, but the weird thing is that **I don't see any message** as if the `doClick` method is never executed.
How do I override an inherited method (`doClick`) in the child class?

Comment: @Liam it does actually thanks to this `A.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);`

Comment: @liam: certainly not. Using `Object.create` is correct. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392857/benefits-of-using-object-create-for-inheritance/17393153#17393153

Comment: You're running the attach click, but are you executing a click?

Comment: @MatheusDal'Pizzol right thx. Arghhh,  since I'm new to oop in javascript I did miss that detail :D. Sorry guys

Comment: I updated your code to include an actual element and it works as expected.

Comment: Well I learnt something new anyway... :)

Comment: @FelixKling It works from the beginning actually, I "only" missed to click :'(, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to execute a click. Your code is working. =)
I will only suggest to put your .doClick() method in A.prototype, so it will be shared by all A instances.

```js
// The parent class
    var Parent = function (jqueryElement) {
        this.jqueryElement = jqueryElement;
    };
    
    Parent.prototype.attachClick = function () {
        var that = this;
         
        this.jqueryElement.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
    
            that.doClick($(this));
        });
    }
    
    Parent.prototype.doClick = function ($element) {
        console.info('click event from parent');
    }
    
    // First child class
    var A = function(jqueryElement) {
        var that = this;
    
        Parent.call(this, jqueryElement);
    
    };
    
    A.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);

    // this is supposed to override the Parent's
    A.prototype.doClick = function ($element) {
       console.info('click event from A');
    };
    
    var test = new A($('.selector'));
    test.attachClick();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="selector">Click me</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ekw6vk43/

Comment: `.doClick() ` is actually shared without the need to define it inside the `A.prototype`, since my code works.

Comment: And A is not supposed to be inherited from.

Comment: Sorry, but in the way your code is written, every new instance of A will create a new .doClick() method in memory. If you want to create it only once and have it shared by all the instances of A, you'll need to put it into A.prototype.

Comment: If there is no problem with the code then the question should be closed with the appropriate close reason (or deleted by the OP), not answered.

Comment: The element responsible for running the task he was testing was missing. Isn't that a "problem with  the code"? Also, there was a method declared in the wrong place.