# Crockford Constructor: As Own Property versus Attached to `__proto__`

Tags: javascript

The title may sound a bit confusing. Please allow me to cast Crockford's constructor into the following simple example and create objects using two different ways. (Browser is FireFox.)

```
var car = function(carSpec) {

  var maker = carSpec.maker;
  var year = carSpec.year;
  var that = {};

  that.getMaker = function () {
    return maker;
  };

  that.getYear = function () {
    return year;
  };

  return that;
};
```

One way to create an object, as Crockford pointed out, is to use `Object.create` method,

```
myCar = Object.create(car({maker: 'Nissan', year: 2004}));
console.log(myCar); // Object {}, on FireFox console.
```

and the methods `getMaker` and `getYear` are attached to the `__proto__`.

The other way is to invoke `car` and let it return an object

```
yourCar = car({maker: 'Ford', year: 2010});
console.log(yourCar); // Object { getMaker: car/that.getMaker(), getYear: car/that.getYear() }
```

and methods `getMaker` and `getYear` becomes the own properties of object `yourCar`.

My questions is: What are the pros and cons of these two ways of object creation from this "Crockford constructor"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage of having methods in `__proto__` or `prototype` is **multiple** copies of created **objects** will point to the **same methods**. Meaning only one copy of each method will be created. Less(relatively) usage of memory. If the methods are attached to the objects itself then each object will have its own copy of the methods.

Comment: So, you are basically saying that `Object.create` in this scenario - applying to this Crockford style constructor - is the same as the more conventional approach relying on `.prototype` and `new`. Is this a correct characterisation?

Comment: In a way yes if you are creating instances without any inheritance. Otherwise here's a good answer(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392857/benefits-of-using-object-create-for-inheritance) on using `Object.create` for inheritance.

Comment: Nice post. Perhaps I prefer "delegation" more than "inheritance". My observation is that, in JavaScript, this term "inheritance" sugar-coats the underlying "delegation" accomplished by prototype chain lookup.

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to call `Object.create` when you already have the complete object that you want. Inheritance is only useful when you have multiple objects that are supposed to share common properties, but in your example `getMaker` and `getYear` are own properties of each car instance.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. But I was asking a different question.

Comment: @Xavier I agree that the `Object.create` makes no sense, since calls of `car` already return real distinct objects(no overlapping property).

Comment: @ PanJunjei For this specific example, I, too, agree with Bergi. But, that was not the question.

Comment: @Xavier What was the question then? I thought you were asking to compare your two ways of object construction in your code snippets.

Comment: @ Bergi Right. Too simple an example to include possible "inheritance" behaviour. The question could perhaps be better rephrased as: How to compare attaching properties to the proptotype chain with assigning them as own properties?

Comment: @Xavier For that, see [`prototype` vs `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/1048572) (it doesn't matter whether you use `new` + `.prototype` or `Object.create` for the instantiation)