# Why the prototype not equal with Object.create()

Tags: javascript, prototype

According to the official [demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) `The Object.create() method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.`

With the following code, why the prototype not equal??

```js
function Shape() {}

function Rectangle() {}

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
console.log(`${Shape.prototype === Rectangle.prototype}`) // false
```

Why `Shape.prototype === Rectangle.prototype` is **false**

Comment: That would mean `Object.create(Shape.prototype) === Shape.prototype`. Do you think `Object.create` should do nothing? =)

Comment: Because [it's a good thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392857/benefits-of-using-object-create-for-inheritance) that they're not the same!

Comment: If you’re interpreting “creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties” as meaning “copies the properties from this object into a new one”, it’s time to read about prototypes! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes Though that behaviour wouldn’t make the objects `===` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

> The Object.create() method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.

`Rectangle.prototype` is an object whose prototype is `Shape.prototype`. That is, `Rectangle.prototype != Shape.prototype`.

In the other hand:

```js
function Shape() {}

function Rectangle() {}

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype)

// true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Rectangle.prototype) == Shape.prototype)
```

In addition, you may use `instanceof` to verify that a given object is an instance of some prototype:

```js
function Shape() {}

function Rectangle() {}

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype)


console.log(Rectangle.prototype instanceof Shape)
```

Comment: @ygweric Because you can't access the prototype of an object directly. `Shape.prototype.prototype` is `undefined`

Comment: @ygweric The ordinary `.prototype` property is not the internal [[prototype]] from which properties are inherited. You'd use `Object.getPrototypeOf` to access that.

Comment: @ygweric: The prototype of an object is not a property named `prototype`. (That property *on a constructor* determines the prototype of objects created by that constructor.) You would check `Object.getPrototypeOf(Shape.prototype) === Rectangle.prototype`.

Comment: console.log(Shape.prototype === Rectangle.prototype.__proto__)

Answer (score 1):

You have an intermediate object here. Object.create has this signature

```
Object.create(proto)
```

where `proto` is the object which should be the prototype of the newly-created object.

`Rectangle.prototype` refers to an object which prototype has set to the `Shape.prototype`. When you use `===` you compare their references, which are different, so why you get false.

See the visualization

```
                        -------          -----
Rectangle.prototype ->  |     |          |   |
                        |proto|  ------> -----   
                        -------            ^  
                                           |
Shape.prototype ----------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `===` on two object references (names) such as `Rectangle.prototype` and `Shape.prototype`, you are testing whether both references actually refer to the very same object. If you have two distinct objects that happen to contain the same values inside them, or two distinct objects where one is the prototype of the other, they will not compare equal.

Your call to `Object.create()` [creates a *new* object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). It will never compare equal to any other object. `Rectangle.prototype` is a brand new object you've just created. It's not a reference to the same object as `Shape.prototype`. The *prototype* of `Rectangle.prototype` is `Shape.prototype`, but that doesn't make them the same object. So they will compare unequal.

By way of contrast, suppose you had done this:

```
Rectangle.prototype = Shape.prototype;
```

Now `Rectangle.prototype` and `Shape.prototype` are both references to *the same object*, because that's what the `=` operator does. Unlike `Object.create()`, the `=` operator doesn't create a new object, only a new reference to the same object. If you then use `===` to compare them, they will compare equal, because the two names literally refer to the very same object.

Answer (score 0):

You can not compare objects using === or ==. You need to write the function to check for every single property plus the number of properties to check equality of the object. you can read about it here --

[Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

Comment: Your right. That is why I mentioned that comparison needs to be done. The link is there to help with the code of comparison for an object. The link gives an extra info how to write the code that is why even the link is gone answers is good enough