# Setting `ConstructorFunc.prototype.constructor = ConstructorFunc`. What is the idea?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Reading a book chapter about inheritance. It gives this example of implementing inheritance.

```
function Mammal() {}
Mammal.prototype = new Animal();
Mammal.prototype.constructor = Mammal;
Mammal.prototype.isPregnant = false;
Mammal.prototype.pairsOfEyes = 1;
```

I don't understand the explanation of why they do `Mammal.prototype.constructor = Mammal`.
Before this line we have that

`Mammal.prototype.constructor === Animal` 
Right? 
So why do they set it to Mammal?

The explanation is as follows:

*After we change the value of the Mammal.prototype property, we will assign the
Mammal constructor function to the Mammal.constructor property in order to
clean up the side effects on the constructor property when you change the value
of a prototype.*

?!

What does that mean?

Is this pattern correct actually or not?

MDN tutorial is also a bit vague on this topic. 
See the example here where Teacher extends Person.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance

*We need to do one more thing before we move on. After adding the last line, Teacher.prototype's constructor property is now equal to Person(), because we just set Teacher.prototype to reference an object that inherits its properties from Person.prototype! Try saving your code, loading the page in a browser, and entering Teacher.prototype.constructor into the console to verify. This can become a problem, so we need to set this right.*

?!?!

So it seems this step is needed. But what is the idea behind it?

I mean who needs this property (later on) and why NOT setting it this way would cause problems?

Comment: Nobody *needs* the property, but it sometimes is handy and setting it to the expected value is the best practice.

Comment: Btw, if you're reading a book that still recommends `Mammal.prototype = new Animal();` instead of `Mammal.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);`, consider buying a different one.

Comment: @Bergi :) OK... Not that I am sure why `Object.create(Animal.prototype)` is better but I am sure you're right... I mean, it seems JS has undergone very rapid development in the last 5-6 years. Maybe that's why.

Comment: Yeah, a recent book should cover `class` syntax instead (or in addition to) the ES5 way, but `Object.create` was introduced in 2011.

Answer (score 3):

> `Mammal.prototype.constructor === Animal` Right? So why do they set it to Mammal?

Right, and that’s not a good thing. `Mammal.prototype` is the prototype for *instances* of `Mammal`, so you want

```
new Mammal().constructor === Mammal
```

not

```
new Mammal().constructor === Animal
```

That’s what the change achieves.

> Is this pattern correct actually or not?

Sort of. It’s very dated – the lazy (but practical) ES3 way of doing things. In ES5, you would use `Object.create(Animal.prototype)`, allowing the parent constructor to actually do something, and call the parent constructor inside the child constructor accordingly:

```
function Mammal() {
    Animal.call(this);
}
```

Nowadays, `class` will do all of this and more for you:

```
class Mammal extends Animal {}
```

Comment: How is `Object.create(Animal.prototype)` better than `new Animal()`? Sorry for the naive question.

Comment: @peter.petrov See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here and https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393153/1048572?Benefits-of-using-Object.create-for-inheritance

Comment: @peter.petrov: All you want to do when setting the prototype as part of inheritance is create an object based off the parent prototype. If the constructor does anything else, you probably *don’t* want to run that. For example, a type that numbers its instances, `var id = 0; function Animal() { this.id = ++id; }` – `Mammal.prototype.id` shouldn’t exist.