# How to Create an inheritance in javascript using functions and classes

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I want to create an inheritance where I have class defined and creating inheritance using function

```
class ClassA{
    constructor(){
    this.name = "Kanike"
    }
}
function ClassB(jkk){
     new ClassA()
    this.last = jkk
    
}
ClassB.prototype = ClassA.prototype
var myClassB = new ClassB("kel");
alert(myClassB.name)//cant be accessed here
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to make a constructor defined with `function` inherit from one defined with `class`? Why? (You should have a good reason, because it’s overcomplicated and provides no portability benefit.)

Comment: You're already using `class`, so why not do it properly and use `class ClassB extends ClassA`? Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance#ECMAScript_2015_Classes

Comment: You can't really make a normal constructor functions "inherit" from classes because to do this properly you would have to invoke the class constructor with a specific `this` value, but class constructors can only be invoked with `new` (with which you can't set `this`). Also `ClassB.prototype = ClassA.prototype` is wrong. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/218196 for more information about how to setup inheritance with constructor functions. But as everyone is saying, just use `class`.

Comment: @Ry- Actually we have a JS package where everything is in Class's and we have our own Product where we used function-based classes. If there is any solution it highly helps us

Comment: @prawin: The solution is for you to switch to `class`. `function` constructors have no advantages except ES5 compatibility, and you can’t extend an ES6 class in any way using only ES5 features.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `extends` keyword is for. Extend the class and you can access both the `name` and `last` fields:

```js
class ClassA {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "Kanike";
  }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {
  constructor(last) {
    super();
    this.last = last;
  }
}

let classB = new ClassB("Kel");
console.log(classB.name, classB.last);
```