# Extending objects functionalities in JavaScript through prototypes

Tags: javascript

I'm studying JavaScript autodidactically, I was searching for ways to inherit from objects and extend their *functionalities* as well...and... wow! it turns out there are several ways to do it.

So there is a popular one which is extending an object *through extend and class keywords* (to say it in short) of which I put an example of what I saw right underneath. Ok, since I come from *C++* and *Python* languages, this is indeed! very helpful... but I'm aware of this is sugar code to help programmers who come from object-oriented languages feel JavaScript cozier. So!, my goal is to know *how to extend objects functionalities* without using the aforementioned method since I'm eager to understanding how js works under the hood (at least to nighing considerably to it) and feeling comfortable with it.

### Note

I know there are posts here on this topic, but i think those don't meet my needs, considering those which (are very good) dig deep into it are from around 2012.

### With class and extend keywords way

REFERENCE: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-extend-an-object-in-javascript/

```js
// Declaring class 
class Profile {

  // Constructor of profile class 
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  getName() {

    // Method to return name 
    return this.name;
  }

  getAge() {

    // Method to return age 
    return this.age;
  }

  getClass() {
    return this;
  }
}

// Class Student extends class Profile  
class Student extends Profile {

  // Each data of class Profile can be 
  // accessed from student class. 
  constructor(name, age, languages) {

    // Acquiring of attributes of parent class 
    super(name, age);
    this.lang = [...languages];
  }

  // Method to display all attributes 
  getDetails() {
    console.log("Name : " + this.name);
    console.log("Age : " + this.age);
    console.log("Languages : " + this.lang);
  }
}

// Creating object of child class with passing of values 
var student1 = new Student("Ankit Dholakia", 24,
  ['Java', 'Python', 'PHP', 'JavaScript']);
student1.getDetails();
```

### I tried this... but I'm not comfortable!

```js
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
Person.prototype.selfPresentation = function() {
  console.log("Hello, my name is " + this.name + "and I'm " + this.age + " years old.");
}

function Worker(name, age, occupation) {
  Person.call(this, name, age);
  this.occupation = occupation;
}
Worker.prototype = new Person;
Worker.prototype.selfPresentation = function() {
  // I think there undoubtedly is a best approach for this...
  this.__proto__.__proto__.selfPresentation.call(this); 
  console.log("I don't breath only, I'm a " + this.occupation);
}

let variable = new Worker("Arturo", 22, "Student");
variable.selfPresentation();
```

### (This is a little aside my goal but..) For inheritance between objects I tried to mimic Object.create method

```js
a = {
  field: "field",
  method: function() {
    console.log("SuperMethod");
  }
}

function inheritHimAll(object) {
  function helperFunction() {}
  helperFunction.prototype = object;
  return new helperFunction;
}

b = inheritHimAll(a);
console.log(b.__proto__)
```

What would be the best approach for extending objects in javascript?

Comment: Why would you try to mimic `Object.create` instead of just using it? Notice that is the most basic primitive in JS object inheritance.

Comment: Define "best"..

Comment: Why do you say "JavaScript 2020" when you're actually asking about the *old* way of doing it? The `class` syntax is the 2020 way.

Comment: Why would you avoid ES6 classes? They represent C-like classes which is much better than the nitty-gritty prototype nightmare that came before it...

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl He said: **I'm eager to understanding how js works under the hood**

Comment: Using `Worker.prototype = new Person;` is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17392857/1048572) and using `__proto__` is outright deprecated.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl No, they do *not* represent C-like classes. They do represent prototypical inheritance, just with nicer syntax. (Apart from the fact that C has no `class`es).

Comment: Even though I know how the prototype chain works and stuff like that, I prefer to use the `class` syntax because it's much more intuitive and less error-prone. I think many other JS programmers feel that way.

Comment: I guess i used wrong terminologies, what i want is to make this happen correctly without recoursing to class and extend keywords, this is more for conceptual understanding, just that. Indeed @Barmar, that's why i tried to clarify im attempting to have more culture regarding to this.

Comment: If you want to compare two ways of doing something, it would be better if you actually implemented the same functionality in both snippets. Why is one of them `Person/Student` and the other `Perso/Worker`, and the methods are all different?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, C doesnt have classes as far as im aware, but C++ does.

Comment: The following links might help, if you had not already seen them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes and also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: I said, "C-like" not "C". I know that C only has structs, but other C-like languages that follow OOP have very similar structures, but you and I digress...

Comment: @Barmar, you are correct, the first example is exactly one that was mentioned in a post of GeeksForGeeks, which i didnt reference, the other one is mine, that's why there exists a difference between class names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would be the best approach for extending objects in javascript?

This is quite a subjective question, but I use the [`class` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) when I can. They are more intuitive, and require less boilerplate code.

However, I think you are more interested in knowing how to do inheritance *without* the `class` syntax. Here's what I would change from your example:

1. Don't create a new instance of the class for prototype. The properties all live in the object, not in the prototype. Instead, use [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to create a new object with the class's prototype. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17393153/9253414) for more information about this.
2. Never use `__proto__`. Instead, call the function from the class's prototype manually or use [`Object.getPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf).

```js
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}
Person.prototype.selfPresentation = function() {
  console.log("Hello, my name is " + this.name + "and I'm " + this.age + " years old.");
}

function Worker(name, age, occupation) {
  Person.call(this, name, age);
  this.occupation = occupation;
}
Worker.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Worker.prototype.selfPresentation = function() {
  Person.prototype.selfPresentation.call(this); 
  console.log("I don't breath only, I'm a " + this.occupation);
}

let variable = new Worker("Arturo", 22, "Student");
variable.selfPresentation();
```

Comment: is there a reason to not use __proto__ regardless of the fact that is lengthy and sort of confusing? sorry, just curious. @DPardal

Comment: @ArturoBolívarLabautdelRío [`__proto__` is deprecated.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto)