# Can anyone explain why the prototype chain shouldn't say `Dog`->`Animal`->`Creature`?

Tags: javascript, console, prototype, prototype-chain

I was looking for good example of Javascript prototypical inheritance on SO and this question, [Benefits of using 'Object.create' for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392857/benefits-of-using-object-create-for-inheritance/17393153#answer-17393153), has an excellent answer and so I tried to push my luck by adding another object type to the prototype chain and I found something that looks strange.

The original listing has `Dog` inheriting from `Animal` and we can see `Animal` in the prototype chain.  However, if we add `Creature` and have `Animal` inheriting from that then `Animal` disappears from the **reported** prototype chain if we use console.info.

Can anyone explain why the prototype chain shouldn't say `Dog`->`Animal`->`Creature` ?

[image]

Here is code listing

```
"use strict";

//https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html
var Creature = (function () {
    function Creature() {
        return this;
    }

    Creature.prototype.deadOrAlive = function () {
        console.log("alive"); //hard code for now
    }

    return Creature;
}());

var Animal = (function () {

    Animal.prototype = Object.create(Creature.prototype);

    function Animal() {
        return this;
    }

    Animal.prototype.move = function (distanceInMeters) {
        if (distanceInMeters === void 0) {
            distanceInMeters = 0;
        }
        console.log("Animal moved " + distanceInMeters + "m.");
    };

    return Animal;
}());

var Dog = (function () {

    /* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392857/benefits-of-using-object-create-for-inheritance/17393153#answer-17393153 */
    Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

    function Dog() {
        return this;
    }
    Dog.prototype.bark = function () {
        console.log("Woof! Woof!");
    };
    return Dog;
}());

var dog = new Dog();
dog.bark();
dog.move(10);
dog.bark();
dog.deadOrAlive();
//debugger;
```

Comment: "*Can anyone explain why the prototype chain shouldn't say `Dog`->`Animal`->`Creature`?*" - the prototype chain is `dog`->`Dog.prototype`->`Animal.prototype`->`Creature.prototype`->`Object.prototype`->`null`. What the debugger shows you are just derived labels on these objects, and not always helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague at a Javascript boot camp of which I am member has come up with a one-line solution, just use `Object.setPrototypeOf( Animal.prototype, Creature.prototype )`.   Thanks, Ray!

```
//https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html
"use strict";

var Creature = (function () {
    function Creature() {
        return this;
    }

    Creature.prototype.deadOrAlive = function () {
        console.log("alive"); //hard code for now
    }

    return Creature;
}());

var Animal = (function () {
    Object.setPrototypeOf( Animal.prototype, Creature.prototype )

    function Animal() {
        return this;
    }

    Animal.prototype.move = function (distanceInMeters) {
        if (distanceInMeters === void 0) {
            distanceInMeters = 0;
        }
        console.log("Animal moved " + distanceInMeters + "m.");
    };

    return Animal;
}());

var Dog = (function () {
    /* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392857/benefits-of-using-object-create-for-inheritance/17393153#answer-17393153 */
    Object.setPrototypeOf( Dog.prototype, Animal.prototype )

    function Dog() {
        return this;
    }
    Dog.prototype.bark = function () {
        console.log("Woof! Woof!");
    };
    return Dog;
}());

var dog = new Dog();
dog.bark();
dog.move(10);
dog.bark();
dog.deadOrAlive();
//debugger;
```

[image]

Comment: If you're using ES6 `Object.setPrototypeOf`, you may as well just use an ES6 `class` declaration :-) The use of `Object.create` is still recommended for ES5 code, and very educational.