# Javascript Inheritance Chain

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

```
function Student() {
}

Student.prototype.sayName = function() {
  console.log(this.name)
}

function EighthGrader(name) {
  this.name = name
  this.grade = 8
}

EighthGrader.prototype = Object.create(Student)

const carl = new EighthGrader("carl")
carl.sayName() // console.logs "carl" TypeError HERE
carl.grade // 8
```

Why do I get a TypeError when I use Student as the argument for Object.create? I know it can be fixed using Student.prototype instead.

I thought the sayName() method could still be accessed according to the prototype chain?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because `sayName` is not defined on `Student` and therefore not on `EighthGrader.prototype`. `sayName` is defined on `Student.prototype`, so the following is the correct way of establishing inheritance:

```
EighthGrader.prototype = Object.create(Student.prototype);
```

Inheritance always works by having the child class' `prototype` "inherit" from the parent class' `prototype`.

See also [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392857/benefits-of-using-object-create-for-inheritance/17393153#17393153)