# Why the result of console.log will be different before and after I refresh the browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have the code snippet like this:

```js
function Person(myName,myAge) {
            this.name = myName
            this.age = myAge
        }
        Person.prototype = {
            say:function() {
            console.log("Hi");
            }
        }
let person = new Person("John",12);
console.log(Person.prototype)
console.log(Person.prototype.constructor)
console.log(person.__proto__)
```

I can't understand why when I first execute the code(by right click and open the file in chrome),the devtool will log:

```
Object
ƒ Object() { [native code] }
Object
```

But when I refresh the browser,the devtool will log:

```
{say: ƒ}
ƒ Object() { [native code] }
{say: ƒ}
```

So, in the first log,it actually didn't log the complete object,right?It just log `Object` in order to tell you that it is an object instead of telling you the content of this object.Why?What does the browser do when I refresh it?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788187/javascript-better-way-to-modify-function-prototype) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23807805/why-is-mutating-the-prototype-of-an-object-bad-for-performance) might help you why this is happening. This has been a long time thing on chrome and webkit.

Comment: @AbhishekKumarTiwari No,my doubts are not there.I just can't understand why the devtool will log `Object` when first execute the code while it will log the complete object when refreshing the browser.Check my question above.

Comment: I mean the first time when I try to log `Person.prototype`,it should just log `{say: ƒ}` instead of `Object`

Answer (score 0):

Changing the prototype directly is not a good idea. No matter if you use `setPrototypeOf` or directly `.prototype`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

> **Warning**: Changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, **currently a very slow operation in every browser and JavaScript engine**. In addition, the effects of altering inheritance are subtle and far-flung, and are not limited to simply the time spent in the Object.setPrototypeOf(...) statement, but may extend to any code that has access to any object whose [[Prototype]] has been altered.
>
> Because this feature is a part of the language, it is still the **burden
> on engine developers to implement that feature performantly** (ideally).
> Until engine developers address this issue, if you are concerned about
> performance, you should avoid setting the [[Prototype]] of an object.
> Instead, create a new object with the desired [[Prototype]] using
> Object.create().

You should use [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) instead with the desired prototype.

Comment: My doubts are not there.I just can't understand why the devtool will log Object when first execute the code while it will log the complete object when refreshing the browser.Check my question above

Comment: It's clearly written in the answer, `currently a very slow operation in every browser and JavaScript engine` .  Setting the prototype directly is never the way to go because of all the problems like yours it brings.

Comment: No, this isn't the question here

Comment: @AbhishekKumarTiwariA You mean it is because "changing prototype is a slow operation" that it will only log `Object` for the first time,and later the operation is done and  
 it logs the `{say: ƒ}`,right?

Comment: But i am still confused here since what I change is `prototype` instead of `[[prototype]]` or 
 `__proto__`.Is changing the `prototype` also a slow operation?