# Object.create(Function.prototype) => create Function which inherits properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for a way to construct a function that has some inheritance.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype

What I am looking for is an object that is a function that can be instantiated in a program, but that has *new* properties attached to it's prototype.

So, what we shouldn't do is this:

```
Function.prototype.x = function(){

};

Function.prototype.y = function(){

};
```

so what I want to do is something like:

```
const proto = Object.create(Function.prototype);

proto.x = function(){};

proto.y = function(){};
```

however, at some point later in the program, I would like to actually define the function body for proto, so that I can actually call proto like a function:

```
proto();
```

is there a way to do this? The above definitely does not work :)

This is a little closer, and the error message is telling:

```
function F(){

}

F.prototype = Function.prototype;

var f = new F();

f.apply(null);
```

Run the above and we get:

> TypeError: Function.prototype.apply was called on [object Object],
>   which is a object and not a function
>           at Object. (/Users/amills/WebstormProjects/oresoftware/suman/exp7.js:15:3)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
>           at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
>           at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
>           at startup (node.js:160:18)
>           at node.js:449:3

Comment: I've tried this, the further you go down this road, the more hacky it gets. What do you want to achieve with that? Why does the instance have to be a function? why can't you simply attach the function to the instance?

Comment: I believe you, even given the little amount of experimentation that I have done - I am creating a library/API. Inheritance just means more performance, because prototypes are shared objects - what I want is an object that is a function but whose prototype is shared, but is not the function prototype :) probably not going to happen :(

Comment: In compatible engines, you can define a `class` that `extends Function` ([support](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Function_is_subclassable)).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski could you perhaps show an example of that? If ES6 can do it, why wouldn't ES5 be able to?

Comment: @AlexMills A function is recognized by an internal property, [`[[Call]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist). This isn't inherited from a prototype and `Object.create()` doesn't have any mechanism to define it. – `class` works by invoking the `Function` constructor through `super()`, which does set `[[Call]]`.

Comment: A possible alternative could be to [change the function's prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) after it's been created – `var foo = function () {}; Object.setPrototypeOf(foo, proto);`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski yeah I was thinking that, I will experiment

Comment: @JonathanLonowski changing the "_____proto_____" of a function after it's declared/created, seems to work, but I wonder if there are any caveats?

Comment: You're painting yourself into a corner. Through the usage of internal Classes in modern JS-engines you don't even get any performance or memory-gain out of this. On the other hand, you complicate the instantiation-process wich makes this part slower. And the worst of all, you might confuse the users of your Lib, wich usually leads to more errors.

Comment: by internal classes you mean Function? I agree with what you're saying. This is internal to my library and is not anywhere close to the API itself, otherwise I definitely wouldn't mess with it.

Comment: I added an answer, see if you agree with the mechanics, if not the motivation.

Comment: It's an interesting question and desirable behavior but I tend to agree with @Thomas at least for ES5. Main reason I gave an ES6 answer was that you tagged it with `node.js`, so it would seem like ES5 would be a non-issue. Are you stuck on an ES5-based version of Node? If so, I'm pretty sure this question has been asked a number of times here.

Comment: Given you are using nodejs, you might be interested in [How to extend `Function` with ES6 classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36871299/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this is as follows!

**step 1**

> create an `Object` which inherits from `Function.prototype`

```
const obj = Object.create(Function.prototype);  // inherits many properties, etc
```

**step 2**

> later in your program declare the function

```
const f = function(){};
```

**step 3**

> set the `__proto__` of `f` to `obj`

`Object.setPrototypeOf(f,obj);`  which is basically equivalent to `f.__proto__ = obj;`

....this seems to work without any problems, thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: note: this works, except you will not be able to call f.apply() or f.call() or f.toString(), so that will probably be a problem.

Comment: Please just only show `Object.setPrototypeOf` and don't even mention the deprecated `__proto__` :-)

Comment: @AlexMills Then make `obj` inherit from `Function.prototype`

Comment: @Oriol thanks, I tried that, and it worked perfectly, good call