# Return Function or Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My code is already working but I want to ask if there's any change to make my function declared as an object instead if no parameters has been provided?

this is my **mixin** function below:

```
import Page from "@/models/Page.js";

/**
 * @param  {number} pageId id in page table
 */
export default function (pageId) {
  return {
    data() {
      return {
        page: Page
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.initPageContents();
    },
    methods: {
      async initPageContents() {
        if (pageId) {
          await Page.addPage(pageId);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**I call it either**

```
  mixins: [
    pageMixin(24),
  ],
```

**or**

```
  mixins: [
    pageMixin(),
  ],
```

Now with my question again. is it possible to call it as an object that will also behave like the function that doesnt have a parameter?

```
  mixins: [
    pageMixin,
  ],
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46063764/4608364) for a possible solution (also possible duplicate?)

Comment: @Quelklef will check on this and will tag it if true

Comment: @Quelklef just an update. It's quite related but I think thats not what im looking for

Comment: You sure? My understanding is that it would let you have an object `pageMixinObj` that acts under almost all circumstances like `pageMixin()`, except that it's callable so `pageMixinObj(...args)` is equal to `pageMixin(...args)`. This seems, to me, to match your situation quite well.

Comment: @Quelklef it should also return an object data same as `pageMixin()` when you call `pageMixin` without the open and close parentheses

Comment: Yes, it would. When I have some free time I will make an answer that explains better what I am thinking.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't - what you have in that array is a function reference, which means you can only do this:

```
mixins[0]()
```

To call your function. If you want the *return value* of the function to be stored in the array, you'd need to do what you were already doing:

```
mixins: [
  pageMixin()
]
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not a Javascript expert, but I have cobbled together what I believe is a solution. It is based off of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340383/can-a-javascript-object-have-a-prototype-chain-but-also-be-a-function/46063764#46063764).

I will reduce your question to the following: "I have a function `f`. I would like an object `o` so that `o` behaves like `f()`, but `o(a, b, c, ...)` behaves like `f(a, b, c, ...)`"

Say, for example, we have a function for creating "people":

```js
function makePerson(firstname, age) {
  firstname = firstname || "Jackson";
  age = age || 17;
  return { firstname: firstname, age: age };
}
```

and we'd like `makePerson` to act like `makePerson()`. I will consider it sufficient to have that `makePerson.firstname == "Jackson"` and `makePerson.age == 17`. That is, we care about making all the attributes correct.

We can do this by setting the prototype of `makePerson` to a new function object which has the attributes that we desire:

```
// Create a function object
const functionObject = Object.create(Function.prototype);
// Get the default value
const defaultValue = makePerson();
// Copy all the attributes from the default value to the function object
Object.assign(functionObject, defaultValue);
// Make the function object the prototype of our function
Object.setPrototypeOf(makePerson, functionObject);
```

and see that this works:

```
console.log(makePerson.firstname); // Jackson
console.log(makePerson.age); // 17

// Still works as a function
console.log(makePerson()); // { name: 'Jackson', age: 17 }
console.log(makePerson("Oliver", 50)); // { name: 'Oliver', age: 50 }
```

---

If you want, you could wrap this all up in a function:

```
function emulateDefault(func) {
  /* Return a function `newFunc` such that `newFunc` behaves like
     `func()` and `newFunc(...args)` behaves like `func(...args)`. */

  // Clone `func`
  const funcClone = Object.create(Function.prototype);
  Object.assign(funcClone, func);

  // Create a function object
  const functionObject = Object.create(Function.prototype);
  // Get the default value
  const defaultValue = func();
  // Copy all the attributes from the default value to the function object
  Object.assign(functionObject, defaultValue);
  // Make the function object the prototype of our function
  Object.setPrototypeOf(funcClone, functionObject);

  return funcClone;
}
```

and then you could write `pageMixin` like:

```
const pageMixin = emulateDefault(function() { ... });
```

---

I want to note that I am not 100% positive about everything that is going on here, and there may be edge cases that I have not accounted for. In particular, [Javascript cloning is particularly difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object), so `emulateDefault` may have issues due to that, and I don't know the details of `Object.new`, `Object.setPrototypeOf`, or `Object.assign`.

Comment: Can the downvoter offer feedback to improve my answer?